# Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, date-format, time-format

How can I convert seconds to an `HH-MM-SS` string using JavaScript?

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6313008/22470

Answer (score 378, accepted):

**Updated (2020):**

Please use @Frank's one line solution:

```
new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().substring(11, 16)
```

If **SECONDS<3600** and if you want to show only **MM:SS** then use below code:

```
new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().substring(14, 19)
```

It is by far the best solution.

---

**Old answer:**

Use the [`Moment.js`](http://momentjs.com) library.

Comment: @J.J. Crowder, you are right. But this answer was given on 2009, that time it was a good ideia. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Cleiton, your updated answer is not full. I tried it as is and got: `TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'clearTime'`.

Comment: Granted Moment.js isn't all that big but if all you're doing with it is to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss, it seems like a bit of overkill. Rather use one of the functions suggested in these or other answers.

Comment: This answer is, if anything, partially wrong. What happens if the amount exceeds 86400 seconds? ;)

Comment: I think the other solution is better than throwing another js library in the mix.

Comment: Adding library for one simple action i think shouldn't be accepted answer. Yes, this works, but there is better solutions!!!

Comment: Using this library for one minor task like this adds **`59,024 bytes`** to your project for the same effect that about **`53 bytes`** will give you. . . From [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279340/8112776): `new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);`

Comment: great, but based on requirements if you need it or not

Comment: From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString): "The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively)."

Comment: As long as your number of hours doesn't go over... 24?

Comment: This is plain wrong! As others have pointed put if you have more than a day's worth of secods the answer is incorrect. USE WITH CAUTION!
See Santiago Hernández's answer below.

Comment: `substr` has been deprecated. Answer should probably be updated to use `substring` instead.

Answer (score 574):

You can manage to do this without any external JavaScript library with the help of JavaScript Date method like following:

```
const date = new Date(null);
date.setSeconds(SECONDS); // specify value for SECONDS here
const result = date.toISOString().slice(11, 19);
```

Or, as per [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538464/frank)'s comment; a one liner:

```
new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().slice(11, 19);
```

Comment: I don't know why everyone is adding extra libraries or doing the math manually when this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This can even be shortened to one line:

`new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will overflow after 24 hours, preventing you from showing more than this length of time. Perfect solution if you have less than 24 hours in seconds.

Comment: This does not work for me in IE11, I get `Object doesn't support property or method 'toISOString'`

Comment: As @renatoargh has stated, this solution can only be used for seconds less equal 24 hours, be careful otherwise.

Comment: This needs example input & example output.

Comment: although this is working, I keep getting the following error: `ERROR RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString`

Comment: If you modulus the seconds using the number of seconds in a day, this works for times >= 1 day.  `new Date(printTime % (60 * 60 * 24)) * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)`.

Comment: for `MM:SS` -> `...substr(14, 5)`. I do this after checking if `SECONDS < 3600`

Comment: I found this on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) docs and thought it might be helpful.

`let [hour, minute, second] = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US").split(/:| /)`

Comment: It is fine to do "new Date" every second? (considering I´m printing a clock) or is it better to reuse date variable and just change seconds every time?

Comment: Nowadays, String.substr() is deprecated. Use String.slice() or String.substring instead.

Comment: But this doesn't display the seconds. Just the hours and minitues :/

Comment: `substr` is deprecated. Use `substring(11, 19)` or `substring(14,19)` instead

Answer (score 216):

I don't think any built-in feature of the standard Date object will do this for you in a way that's more convenient than just doing the math yourself.

```
hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
totalSeconds %= 3600;
minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Example:

```js
let totalSeconds = 28565;
let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
totalSeconds %= 3600;
let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
let seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

console.log("hours: " + hours);
console.log("minutes: " + minutes);
console.log("seconds: " + seconds);

// If you want strings with leading zeroes:
minutes = String(minutes).padStart(2, "0");
hours = String(hours).padStart(2, "0");
seconds = String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");
console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer because it doesn't overflow if more than 24 hours.

Comment: Edge case perhaps, yet something to be aware of: suppose a value such as totalSeconds = 1739.8395. (T.J. mentions fractional portions in comment above.) Formula computes "seconds" as 59.839500000000044. If a person wants to round up, then 59 seconds becomes 60 seconds. Meaning, "seconds" value needs to be set to 0, and 1 minute needs to be added to "minutes". And if "minutes" value happened to be 59, "minutes" value becomes 60, and so "minutes" needs to be reset to 0, and 1 hour needs to be added to "hours".

Comment: @mg1075 - The simplest solution there would be to start out with `totalSeconds = Math.round(totalSeconds);`. :-)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4228356

Answer (score 139):

I know this is kinda old, but...

ES2015:

```
var toHHMMSS = (secs) => {
    var sec_num = parseInt(secs, 10)
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600)
    var minutes = Math.floor(sec_num / 60) % 60
    var seconds = sec_num % 60

    return [hours,minutes,seconds]
        .map(v => v < 10 ? "0" + v : v)
        .filter((v,i) => v !== "00" || i > 0)
        .join(":")
}
```

It will output:

```
toHHMMSS(129600) // 36:00:00
toHHMMSS(13545) // 03:45:45
toHHMMSS(180) // 03:00
toHHMMSS(18) // 00:18
```

Comment: What about fractions of a second? 03:45:45.xxx?

Answer (score 44):

As Cleiton pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322771/259953), [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) can be used for this:

```
moment().startOf('day')
        .seconds(15457)
        .format('H:mm:ss');
```

Comment: What happens if the number of seconds exceeds a day?

Comment: @GiladPeleg if the number of seconds exceeds a day, number of days is calculated internally and it will only return the remaining hours, minutes and seconds. If you want to count number of days as well, you can try `moment().startOf('year').seconds(30000000).format('DDD HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: What happens if the number of seconds exceeds a year?

Comment: @OrangePot if the number of seconds exceeds a year, number of years is calculated internally and it will only return the remaining days, hours, minutes and seconds. If you want to count number of years as well, you can try `.format('YYYY DDD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: But this cannot be made optional. That might look ugly.

Answer (score 26):

Here's a simple function for converting times that might help

```
function formatSeconds(seconds) {
    var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
}
```

Comment: formatSeconds(3919);
//Returns 01:05:19

Excellent Function .. Like it

Comment: Like said before, this will overflow after 24 hours

Answer (score 19):

This does the trick:

```
function secondstotime(secs)
{
    var t = new Date(1970,0,1);
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0,8);
    if(secs > 86399)
        s = Math.floor((t - Date.parse("1/1/70")) / 3600000) + s.substr(2);
    return s;
}
```

(Sourced from [here](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=46860))

Answer (score 15):

```
var  timeInSec = "661"; //even it can be string

String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () { 
   /* extend the String by using prototypical inheritance */
    var seconds = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    seconds = seconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    var time    = hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    return time;
}

alert("5678".toHHMMSS());   // "01:34:38"
console.log(timeInSec.toHHMMSS());   //"00:11:01"
```

we can make this function lot shorter and crisp but that decreases the readability, so we will write it as simple as possible and as stable as possible.

or you can check this working [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sahilosheal/N2B5J/):

Comment: moreover ...  if u want to do all date time thing easily.. use momentJS

Comment: Thanks! no need to include a Library in a browser extension. Simple and works!

Answer (score 12):

I think the most general (and cryptic) solution could be this

```
function hms(seconds) {
  return [3600, 60]
    .reduceRight(
      (pipeline, breakpoint) => remainder =>
        [Math.floor(remainder / breakpoint)].concat(pipeline(remainder % breakpoint)),
      r => [r]
    )(seconds)
    .map(amount => amount.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('-');
}
```

Or to copy & paste the shortest version

```
function hms(seconds) {
  return [3600, 60]
    .reduceRight(
      (p, b) => r => [Math.floor(r / b)].concat(p(r % b)),
      r => [r]
    )(seconds)
    .map(a => a.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('-');
}
```

Some example outputs:

```
> hms(0)
< "00-00-00"

> hms(5)
< "00-00-05"

> hms(60)
< "00-01-00"

> hms(3785)
< "01-03-05"

> hms(37850)
< "10-30-50"

> hms(378500)
< "105-08-20"
```

## How it works

### Algorithm

1. To get hours you divide total seconds by 3600 and floor it.
2. To get minutes you divide **remainder** by 60 and floor it.
3. To get seconds you just use the remainder.

It would also be nice to keep individual amounts in an array for easier formatting.

For example given the input of 3785s the output should be `[1, 3, 5]`, that is 1 hour, 3 minutes and 5 seconds.

### Creating pipeline

Naming the 3600 and 60 constants "breakpoints" you can write this algorithm into function as this

```
function divideAndAppend(remainder, breakpoint, callback) {
  return [Math.floor(remainder / breakpoint)].concat(callback(remainder % breakpoint));
}
```

It returns an array where first item is the amount for given breakpoint and the rest of the array is given by the callback.
Reusing the `divideAndAppend` in callback function will give you a *pipeline of composed* `divideAndAppend` functions. Each one of these
computes amount per given breakpoint and append it to the array making your desired output.

Then you also need the "final" callback that ends this pipeline. In another words you used all breakpoints and now you have only the remainder.
Since you have already the answer at 3) you should use some sort of identity function, in this case `remainder => [remainder]`.

You can now write the pipeline like this

```
let pipeline = r3 => divideAndAppend(
    r3, 
    3600, 
    r2 => divideAndAppend(
        r2, 
        60, 
        r1 => [r1]));

> pipeline(3785)
< [1, 3, 5]
```

Cool right?

### Generalizing using for-loop

Now you can generalize with a variable amount of breakpoints and create a for-loop that will compose individial `divideAndAppend` functions into
the pipeline.
You start with the identity function `r1 => [r1]`, then use the `60` breakpoint and finally use the `3600` breakpoint.

```
let breakpoints = [60, 3600];
let pipeline = r => [r];

for (const b of breakpoints) {
  const previousPipeline = pipeline;
  pipeline = r => divideAndAppend(r, b, previousPipeline);
}

> pipeline(3785)
< [1, 3, 5]
```

### Using `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Now you can rewrite this for-loop into reducer for shorter and more functional code. In other words rewrite function composition into the reducer.

```
let pipeline = [60, 3600].reduce(
  (ppln, b) => r => divideAndAppend(r, b, ppln),
  r => [r]
);

> pipeline(3785)
< [1, 3, 5]
```

The accumulator `ppln` is the pipeline and you are composing it using the previous version of it. The initial pipeline is `r => [r]`.

You can now inline the function `divideAndAppend` and use `Array.prototype.reduceRight` which is the same as `[].reverse().reduce(...)` to make the breakpoints
definitions more natural.

```
let pipeline = [3600, 60]
    .reduceRight(
      (ppln, b) => r => [Math.floor(r / b)].concat(ppln(r % b)),
      r => [r]
    );
```

Which is the final form. Then you just appy mapping to string with padded 0's on left and join the strings with `:` separator;

### More generalizations

Wrapping the reducer into function

```
function decompose(total, breakpoints) {
  return breakpoints.reduceRight(
    (p, b) => r => [Math.floor(r / b)].concat(p(r % b)),
    r => [r]
  )(total);
}

> decompose(3785, [3600, 60])
< [1, 3, 5]
```

you now have very general algorithm you can work with. For example:

#### Convert easily (the weird) us length standards

Given the standards

| Unit | Divisions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 foot | 12 inches |
| 1 yard | 3 feet |
| 1 mile | 1760 yards |

```
> decompose(123_456, [1760 * 3 * 12, 3 * 12, 12])
< [1, 1669, 1, 0]
```

123456 in = 1 mi, 1669 yd, 1 feet and 0 in

#### Or you can somewhat convert to decimal or binary representations

```
> decompose(123_456, [100_000, 10_000, 1000, 100, 10])
< [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

> decompose(127, [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2])
< [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

#### Works also with floating point breakpoints

Since Javascript supports `mod` operator with floating point numbers, you can also do

```
> decompose(26.5, [20, 2.5])
< [1, 2, 1.5]
```

#### The edge case of no breakpoints is also naturally covered

```
> decompose(123, [])
< [123]
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
function toTimeString(seconds) {
  return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an extension to Number class. toHHMMSS() converts seconds to an hh:mm:ss string.

```js
Number.prototype.toHHMMSS = function() {
  var hours = Math.floor(this / 3600) < 10 ? ("00" + Math.floor(this / 3600)).slice(-2) : Math.floor(this / 3600);
  var minutes = ("00" + Math.floor((this % 3600) / 60)).slice(-2);
  var seconds = ("00" + (this % 3600) % 60).slice(-2);
  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

// Usage: [number variable].toHHMMSS();

// Here is a simple test
var totalseconds = 1234;
document.getElementById("timespan").innerHTML = totalseconds.toHHMMSS();
```

```html
// HTML of the test
<div id="timespan"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy to follow version for noobies:

```
 var totalNumberOfSeconds = YOURNUMBEROFSECONDS;
 var hours = parseInt( totalNumberOfSeconds / 3600 );
 var minutes = parseInt( (totalNumberOfSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60 );
 var seconds = Math.floor((totalNumberOfSeconds - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));
 var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

This function should do it :

```
var convertTime = function (input, separator) {
    var pad = function(input) {return input < 10 ? "0" + input : input;};
    return [
        pad(Math.floor(input / 3600)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60)),
        pad(Math.floor(input % 60)),
    ].join(typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':' );
}
```

Without passing a separator, it uses `:` as the (default) separator :

```
time = convertTime(13551.9941351); // --> OUTPUT = 03:45:51
```

If you want to use `-` as a separator, just pass it as the second parameter:

```
time = convertTime(1126.5135155, '-'); // --> OUTPUT = 00-18-46
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xf26snv/7/).

Comment: Could use default parameters like (input ,separator=":"). Also it didn't return anything until I modified it a bit https://paste.ee/p/FDNag

Comment: @madprops : Actually, the version in my answer already sets `:` as default for the `separator` parameter, as I already explained. This is done by the statement `typeof separator !== 'undefined' ?  separator : ':'`. Also, your function is pretty much identical to mine save some cosmetic changes and they should both produce the same output... except my version has much better browser support. Yours won't work in ANY version of Internet Explorer or MS Edge < 14.

Answer (score 5):

Chiming in on this old thread -- the OP stated HH:MM:SS, and many of the solutions work, until you realize you need more than 24 hours listed.  And maybe you don't want more than a single line of code.  Here you go:

```
d=(s)=>{f=Math.floor;g=(n)=>('00'+n).slice(-2);return f(s/3600)+':'+g(f(s/60)%60)+':'+g(s%60)}
```

It returns H+:MM:SS.  To use it, simply use:

```
d(91260);     // returns "25:21:00"
d(960);       // returns "0:16:00"
```

...I tried to get it to  use the least amount of code possible, for a nice one-liner approach.

Comment: Can you provide an expanded/reading version of your code as well so we can more easily see what is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For the special case of **HH:MM:SS.MS** (eq: "00:04:33.637") as used by [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax) to specify **milliseconds**.

> [-][HH:]MM:SS[.m...]
>
> HH expresses the number of hours, MM the number of minutes for a
> maximum of 2 digits, and SS the number of seconds for a maximum of 2
> digits. The m at the end expresses decimal value for SS.

```js
/* HH:MM:SS.MS to (FLOAT)seconds ---------------*/
function timerToSec(timer){
   let vtimer = timer.split(":")
   let vhours = +vtimer[0]
   let vminutes = +vtimer[1]
   let vseconds = parseFloat(vtimer[2])
   return vhours * 3600 + vminutes * 60 + vseconds
}

/* Seconds to (STRING)HH:MM:SS.MS --------------*/
function secToTimer(sec){
  let o = new Date(0)
  let p =  new Date(sec*1000)  
  return new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime())
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[1]
    .split("Z")[0]
}

/* Example: 7hours, 4 minutes, 33 seconds and 637 milliseconds */
const t = "07:04:33.637"
console.log(
  t + " => " +
  timerToSec(t) +
  "s"
)

/* Test: 25473 seconds and 637 milliseconds */
const s = 25473.637 // "25473.637"
console.log(
  s + "s => " + 
  secToTimer(s)
)
```

**Example usage, a milliseconds transport timer:**

```js
/* Seconds to (STRING)HH:MM:SS.MS --------------*/
function secToTimer(sec){
  let o = new Date(0)
  let p =  new Date(sec*1000)  
  return new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime())
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[1]
    .split("Z")[0]
}

let job, origin = new Date().getTime()
const timer = () => {
  job = requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  OUT.textContent = secToTimer((new Date().getTime() - origin) / 1000)
}

requestAnimationFrame(timer)
```

```css
span {font-size:4rem}
```

```html
<span id="OUT"></span>
<br>
<button onclick="origin = new Date().getTime()">RESET</button>
<button onclick="requestAnimationFrame(timer)">RESTART</button>
<button onclick="cancelAnimationFrame(job)">STOP</button>
```

**Example usage, binded to a media element**

```js
/* Seconds to (STRING)HH:MM:SS.MS --------------*/
function secToTimer(sec){
  let o = new Date(0)
  let p =  new Date(sec*1000)  
  return new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime())
    .toISOString()
    .split("T")[1]
    .split("Z")[0]
}

VIDEO.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(e){
  OUT.textContent = secToTimer(e.target.currentTime)
}, false)
```

```css
span {font-size:4rem}
```

```html
<span id="OUT"></span><br>
<video id="VIDEO" width="400" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

---

Outside the question, those functions written in php:

```
<?php 
/* HH:MM:SS to (FLOAT)seconds ------------------*/
function timerToSec($timer){
  $vtimer = explode(":",$timer);
  $vhours = (int)$vtimer[0];
  $vminutes = (int)$vtimer[1];
  $vseconds = (float)$vtimer[2];
  return $vhours * 3600 + $vminutes * 60 + $vseconds;
}
/* Seconds to (STRING)HH:MM:SS -----------------*/
function secToTimer($sec){
  return explode(" ", date("H:i:s", $sec))[0];  
}
```

Comment: You can omit `+ "." + p.getMilliseconds()` by just using 

`new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime()).toISOString().split("T")[1].split("Z")[0]
`

Comment: Looks alright, yes your version it faster: See benchmark http://jsben.ch/4sQY1 
Accepted edit! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at all the answers and not being happy with most of them, this is what I came up with.  I know I am very late to the conversation, but here it is anyway.

```
function secsToTime(secs){
  var time = new Date(); 
  // create Date object and set to today's date and time
  time.setHours(parseInt(secs/3600) % 24);
  time.setMinutes(parseInt(secs/60) % 60);
  time.setSeconds(parseInt(secs%60));
  time = time.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  // time.toString() = "HH:mm:ss GMT-0800 (PST)"
  // time.toString().split(" ") = ["HH:mm:ss", "GMT-0800", "(PST)"]
  // time.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]; = "HH:mm:ss"
  return time;
}
```

I create a new Date object, change the time to my parameters, convert the Date Object to a time string, and removed the additional stuff by splitting the string and returning only the part that need.

I thought I would share this approach, since it removes the need for regex, logic and math acrobatics to get the results in "HH:mm:ss" format, and instead it relies on built in methods.

You may want to take a look at the documentation here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 4):

below is the given code which will convert seconds into hh-mm-ss format:

```
var measuredTime = new Date(null);
measuredTime.setSeconds(4995); // specify value of SECONDS
var MHSTime = measuredTime.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
```

Get alternative method from [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS format in JavaScript](https://www.codespeedy.com/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-format-in-javascript/)

Comment: Did you copy paste from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279340/6563200)?

Answer (score 4):

Simple function to convert seconds into in hh:mm:ss format :

```
function getHHMMSSFromSeconds(totalSeconds) {
    if (!totalSeconds) {
      return '00:00:00';
    }
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds % 3600 / 60);
    const seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    const hhmmss = padTo2(hours) + ':' + padTo2(minutes) + ':' + padTo2(seconds);
    return hhmmss;
}

// function to convert single digit to double digit
function padTo2(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return '00';
    }
    return value < 10 ? String(value).padStart(2, '0') : value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var time1 = date1.getTime();
var time2 = date2.getTime();
var totalMilisec = time2 - time1;

alert(DateFormat('hh:mm:ss',new Date(totalMilisec)))

 /* ----------------------------------------------------------
 *  Field        | Full Form          | Short Form
 *  -------------|--------------------|-----------------------
 *  Year         | yyyy (4 digits)    | yy (2 digits)
 *  Month        | MMM (abbr.)        | MM (2 digits)
                 | NNN (name)         |
 *  Day of Month | dd (2 digits)      | 
 *  Day of Week  | EE (name)          | E (abbr)
 *  Hour (1-12)  | hh (2 digits)      | 
 *  Minute       | mm (2 digits)      | 
 *  Second       | ss (2 digits)      | 
 *  ----------------------------------------------------------
 */
function DateFormat(formatString,date){
    if (typeof date=='undefined'){
    var DateToFormat=new Date();
    }
    else{
        var DateToFormat=date;
    }
    var DAY         = DateToFormat.getDate();
    var DAYidx      = DateToFormat.getDay();
    var MONTH       = DateToFormat.getMonth()+1;
    var MONTHidx    = DateToFormat.getMonth();
    var YEAR        = DateToFormat.getYear();
    var FULL_YEAR   = DateToFormat.getFullYear();
    var HOUR        = DateToFormat.getHours();
    var MINUTES     = DateToFormat.getMinutes();
    var SECONDS     = DateToFormat.getSeconds();

    var arrMonths = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    var arrDay=new Array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    var strMONTH;
    var strDAY;
    var strHOUR;
    var strMINUTES;
    var strSECONDS;
    var Separator;

    if(parseInt(MONTH)< 10 && MONTH.toString().length < 2)
        strMONTH = "0" + MONTH;
    else
        strMONTH=MONTH;
    if(parseInt(DAY)< 10 && DAY.toString().length < 2)
        strDAY = "0" + DAY;
    else
        strDAY=DAY;
    if(parseInt(HOUR)< 10 && HOUR.toString().length < 2)
        strHOUR = "0" + HOUR;
    else
        strHOUR=HOUR;
    if(parseInt(MINUTES)< 10 && MINUTES.toString().length < 2)
        strMINUTES = "0" + MINUTES;
    else
        strMINUTES=MINUTES;
    if(parseInt(SECONDS)< 10 && SECONDS.toString().length < 2)
        strSECONDS = "0" + SECONDS;
    else
        strSECONDS=SECONDS;

    switch (formatString){
        case "hh:mm:ss":
            return strHOUR + ':' + strMINUTES + ':' + strSECONDS;
        break;
        //More cases to meet your requirements.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to give a little explanation to the nice answer above:

```
var totalSec = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var hours = parseInt( totalSec / 3600 ) % 24;
var minutes = parseInt( totalSec / 60 ) % 60;
var seconds = totalSec % 60;

var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + "-" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + "-" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
```

On the second line, since there are 3600 seconds in 1 hour, we divide the total number of seconds by 3600 to get the total number of hours. We use parseInt to strip off any decimal. If totalSec was 12600 (3 and half hours), then parseInt( totalSec / 3600 ) would return 3, since we will have 3 full hours. Why do we need the % 24 in this case? If we exceed 24 hours, let's say we have 25 hours (90000 seconds), then the modulo here will take us back to 1 again, rather than returning 25. It is confining the result within a 24 hour limit, since there are 24 hours in one day.

When you see something like this:

```
25 % 24
```

Think of it like this:

```
25 mod 24 or what is the remainder when we divide 25 by 24
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here satisfies my requirements as I want to be able to handle

1. Large numbers of seconds (days), and
2. Negative numbers

Although those are not required by the OP, it's good practice to cover edge cases, especially when it takes little effort.

It's pretty obvious is that the OP means a NUMBER of seconds when he says *seconds*. Why would peg your function on `String`?

```
function secondsToTimeSpan(seconds) {
    const value = Math.abs(seconds);
    const days = Math.floor(value / 1440);
    const hours = Math.floor((value - (days * 1440)) / 3600);
    const min = Math.floor((value - (days * 1440) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    const sec = value - (days * 1440) - (hours * 3600) - (min * 60);
    return `${seconds < 0 ? '-':''}${days > 0 ? days + '.':''}${hours < 10 ? '0' + hours:hours}:${min < 10 ? '0' + min:min}:${sec < 10 ? '0' + sec:sec}`
}
secondsToTimeSpan(0);       // => 00:00:00
secondsToTimeSpan(1);       // => 00:00:01
secondsToTimeSpan(1440);    // => 1.00:00:00
secondsToTimeSpan(-1440);   // => -1.00:00:00
secondsToTimeSpan(-1);      // => -00:00:01
```

Comment: `secondsToTimeSpan(8991)` returns `6.00:05:51` whereas i think it should return `00:02:29:51`

Answer (score 3):

```
export const secondsToHHMMSS = (seconds) => {
  const HH = `${Math.floor(seconds / 3600)}`.padStart(2, '0');
  const MM = `${Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60}`.padStart(2, '0');
  const SS = `${Math.floor(seconds % 60)}`.padStart(2, '0');
  return [HH, MM, SS].join(':');
};
```

Comment: Great solution! This seems to work best for my situation. I will always need HH to show even if its 00:  Thank you.

Comment: Works greatly with 24H+ seconds as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding seconds to a Date object?

```
Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
    this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + seconds);
};
var dt = new Date();
dt.addSeconds(1234);
```

A sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/j5g2p0dc/5/

Updated:
Sample link was missing so I created a new one.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: dt.addSeconds is not a function

Comment: @Ikrom check the sample, I created a new one in jsfiddle since the old one returned 404 error

Comment: Looks like I didn't release that you were using custom method `addSeconds` on Date object like `Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds){...}`. Yes, it works, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function to convert seconds to hh-mm-ss format based on powtac's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss/6313008#6313008)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/apg8yx1s/)

```
/** 
 * Convert seconds to hh-mm-ss format.
 * @param {number} totalSeconds - the total seconds to convert to hh- mm-ss
**/
var SecondsTohhmmss = function(totalSeconds) {
  var hours   = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds = totalSeconds - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

  // round seconds
  seconds = Math.round(seconds * 100) / 100

  var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours);
      result += "-" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes);
      result += "-" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
  return result;
}
```

Example use

```
var seconds = SecondsTohhmmss(70);
console.log(seconds);
// logs 00-01-10
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of options of solve this problem, and obvious there are good option suggested about, But I wants to add one more optimized code here

```
function formatSeconds(sec) {
     return [(sec / 3600), ((sec % 3600) / 60), ((sec % 3600) % 60)]
            .map(v => v < 10 ? "0" + parseInt(v) : parseInt(v))
            .filter((i, j) => i !== "00" || j > 0)
            .join(":");
}
```

if you don't wants formatted zero with less then 10 number, you can use

```
function formatSeconds(sec) {
  return parseInt(sec / 3600) + ':' + parseInt((sec % 3600) / 60) + ':' + parseInt((sec % 3600) % 60);
```

}

Sample Code http://fiddly.org/1c476/1

Answer (score 2):

In one line, using T.J. Crowder's solution :

```
secToHHMMSS = seconds => `${Math.floor(seconds / 3600)}:${Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60)}:${Math.floor((seconds % 3600) % 60)}`
```

In one line, another solution that also count days :

```
secToDHHMMSS = seconds => `${parseInt(seconds / 86400)}d ${new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)}`
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/martinbean/2bf88c446be8048814cf02b2641ba276

Answer (score 2):

```
var sec_to_hms = function(sec){
var min, hours;
     sec = sec - (min = Math.floor(sec/60))*60;
     min = min - (hours = Math.floor(min/60))*60;
     return (hours?hours+':':'') + ((min+'').padStart(2, '0')) + ':'+ ((sec+'').padStart(2, '0'));
}
alert(sec_to_hms(2442542));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES6 [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to create highly customizable time strings.

Here is the general function to convert a number to an array from a given scale:

```js
function toScaledArray(n,scales){
  function* g(x, n=0){
    if(x>0) {
      yield x%(scales[n]||Infinity);
      yield* g(Math.floor(x/scales[n]),n+1)
    }
  }
  return [...g(n)]
}

console.log(toScaledArray(6,[10,10]))
console.log(toScaledArray(2000,[30,12]))
console.log(toScaledArray(45000,[24,30,12]))
```

So, we can use it to create time strings as follows:

```
> toScaledArray(45000,[60,60]).reverse().join(":")
< '12:30:0'
> toScaledArray(1234,[60,60]).reverse().join(":")
< '20:34'
```

The function can be also written in one line:

```
[...(function* g(x,n=0,scales=[60,60]){if(x>0) {yield x%(scales[n]||Infinity); yield* g(Math.floor(x/scales[n]),n+1,scales)}})(45000)].reverse().join("-")
```

Functions above will omit the leading zeros, if you want to convert a string into precisely 'HH-MM-SS', you can use

```
[...(function* g(x,n=0,scales=[60,60]){if(x>0||n<3) {yield x%(scales[n]||Infinity); yield* g(Math.floor(x/scales[n]),n+1,scales)}})(45000)].reverse().map(x=>String(x).padStart(2, '0')).join("-")
```

Also, if what you need is '[H:]MM:SS', here we have:

```js
Number.prototype.toTimeString = function(){
  return [...(function* g(x,n=0,scales=[60,60]){if(x>0||n<2) {yield x%(scales[n]||Infinity); yield* g(Math.floor(x/scales[n]),n+1,scales)}})(this)].map((x,n)=>n<2?String(x).padStart(2,'0'):x).reverse().join(":")
}

console.log(12,(12).toTimeString())
console.log(345,(345).toTimeString())
console.log(6789,(6789).toTimeString())
```

and you can also have `D(ay)` or even `M(onth)` and `Y(ear)` (not precisely though) as follows:

```
> toScaledArray(123456789,[60,60,24,30,12]).map((x,n)=>n<2?String(x).padStart(2,'0'):x).reverse().join(":")
< '3:11:18:21:33:09'
```

Here the output means "3 years 11 months 18 days 21 hours 33 minutes and 9 seconds"

In conclusion, this is a highly customizable way to convert a number into scaled arrays, which can be used in time string conversion, human readable byte conversion or even change for paper money.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code:

```
int ss = nDur%60;
nDur   = nDur/60;
int mm = nDur%60;
int hh = nDur/60;
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using AngularJS, a simple solution is to filter the value with the [date API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), which converts milliseconds to a string based on the requested format. Example:

```
<div>Offer ends in {{ timeRemaining | date: 'HH:mm:ss' }}</div>
```

Note that this expects milliseconds, so you may want to multiply timeRemaining by 1000 if you are converting from seconds (as the original question was formulated).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the case some have mentioned where the number of seconds is more than a day. Here's an adapted version of @Harish Anchu's top-rated answer that accounts for longer periods of time:

```
function secondsToTime(seconds) {
  const arr = new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8).split(':');

  const days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  arr[0] = parseInt(arr[0], 10) + days * 24;

  return arr.join(':');
}
```

Example:

```
secondsToTime(101596) // outputs '28:13:16' as opposed to '04:13:16'
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}

// For Example :
alert("186".toHHMMSS());
```

Answer (score 1):

Already many answers, but my requirements were:

- convert to duration (i.e., should work for values larger than 24 hours)
- care about the decimals of seconds up to given decimal precision
- truncate the preceding hours and mins if zero.

```js
const seconds2duration = ( seconds, decimals=0 ) => {
    let fraction = ( seconds - Math.floor( seconds ) ).toFixed( decimals );
    fraction = decimals === 0 ? '' : fraction.slice( 1 );
    const [ hours, mins, secs ] = [ seconds / 3600, seconds % 3600 / 60, seconds % 3600 % 60 ].map( ( x ) => String( Math.floor( x ) ).padStart( 2, '0' ) );
    if ( hours === '00' && mins === '00' ) {
        return secs + fraction;
    } else if ( hours === '00' ) {
        return [ mins, secs + fraction ].join( ':' );
    } else {
        return [ hours, mins, secs + fraction ].join( ':' );
    }
};

console.log(seconds2duration(25*3600 + 0*60 + 41 + 0.333, 0)); // 25:00:41
console.log(seconds2duration(0*3600 + 5*60 + 41 + 0.333, 0)); // 05:41
console.log(seconds2duration(0*3600 + 5*60 + 41 + 0.333, 1)); // 05:41.3
console.log(seconds2duration(0*3600 + 0*60 + 41 + 0.333, 2)); // 41.33
```

Answer (score 0):

When I picture a clock or a timer, I would do it as shown below:

```
const secondsTo_HHMMSS = (seconds) => {
      //format to a readable friendly timer
      let hour = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
      let minute = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
      let second = seconds % 60;

      if(hour.toString().length === 1) {
            hour = `0${hour}`;
      }
      if(minute.toString().length === 1) {
            minute = `0${minute}`;
      }
      if(second.toString().length === 1) {
            second = `0${second}`;
      };

      let timer = `${hour}-${minute}-${second}`;

      return timer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option could be to use Intl.DateTimeFormat. Example:

```
const timeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-US', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'UTC'
});

const endTimeFormatted = timeFormat.format(new Date(SECS * 1000); //hour in secs
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use [Sugar](http://sugarjs.com).

```
Date.create().reset().set({seconds: 180}).format('{mm}:{ss}');
```

This example returns '03:00'.

Comment: That sounded good !After checking, it does not returns 03:00, but for any value entered, just 00:00.

Comment: They might have changed their API. I've updated the code (it's 2 years too late and you probably moved on, but I thought others might find it useful).

Answer (score -4):

I've used this code before to create a simple timespan object:

```
function TimeSpan(time) {
this.hours = 0;
this.minutes = 0;
this.seconds = 0;

while(time >= 3600)
{
    this.hours++;
    time -= 3600;
}

while(time >= 60)
{
    this.minutes++;
    time -= 60;
}

this.seconds = time;
}

var timespan = new Timespan(3662);
```

Comment: looping results is a very bad coding technique and should never be used it will hog your processing power and give you a laggy site