# Output is in seconds. convert to hh:mm:ss format in php

Tags: php, time

1. My output is in the format of 290.52262423327 seconds. How can i change this to 00:04:51?
2. The same output i want to show in seconds and in HH:MM:SS format, so if it is seconds, i want to show only 290.52 seconds.(only two integers after decimal point)? how can i do this?

I am working in php and the output is present in `$time` variable. want to change this `$time` into `$newtime` with HH:MM:SS and `$newsec` as 290.52.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you looking for a duration or a time stamp?

Comment: duplicate of **[Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/67332)** or **[Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870843/67332)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you could show the code that is used, it could help to spot the problem

Answer (score 134, accepted):

1. 

```
function foo($seconds) {
  $t = round($seconds);
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $t/3600, floor($t/60)%60, $t%60);
}

echo foo('290.52262423327'), "\n";
echo foo('9290.52262423327'), "\n";
echo foo(86400+120+6), "\n";
```

prints

```
00:04:51
02:34:51
24:02:06
```

2. 

```
echo round($time, 2);
```

Update Note:

```
function foo($seconds) {
  $t = round($seconds);
  // Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float ***.** to int loses precision
  // return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60);

  // return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $t/3600, ($t%3600)/60, $t%60);
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $t/3600, floor($t/60)%60, $t%60);
}
```

Comment: I ran into some extreme unsuccessful divisions and subtracting functions trying to achieve what you did in that one line :) `sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/3600),($t/60%60), $t%60)`

Answer (score 26):

Try this one

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 90);
```

Comment: This solution will work for any values less than the number of seconds in a day, but will reset to 00:00:00 for values ≥ 86400.

Comment: any idea on how to make it work for values >86400 ??

Comment: This is misleading: `gmdate()` accepts a Unix timestamp as the second argument, so effectively you are getting the "H:i:s" portion 90 seconds after January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT, of course if you go over the number of seconds in a day (86400), you will be getting the "H:i:s" portion of the next day. Only use this if you are guaranteed to always have less than a day's worth of seconds.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: A comment pointed out that the previous answer fails if the number of seconds exceeds a day (86400 seconds). Here's an updated version. The OP did not specify this requirement so this may be implemented differently than the OP might expect, and there may be much better answers here already. I just couldn't stand having provided an answer with this bug.

```
$iSecondsIn = 290.52262423327;

// Account for days.
$iDaysOut = 0;
while ($iSecondsIn >= 86400) {
    $iDaysOut += 1;
    $iSecondsIn -= 86400;
}

// Display number of days if appropriate.
if ($iDaysOut > 0) {
    print $iDaysOut.' days and ';
}

// Print the final product.
print date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, $iSecondsIn));
```

---

The old version, with the bug:

```
$iSeconds = 290.52262423327;
print date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, $iSeconds));
```

Comment: This answer is also going to be problematic if your `$iSeconds` goes over 86399 (the number of seconds in a day). 86401 will give you 00:00:01.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

For till `23:59:59` hours you can use PHP default function

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 86399);
```

Which will only return the result till `23:59:59`

If your seconds is more then 86399 than 
with the help of @VolkerK answer

```
$time = round($seconds);
echo sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($time/3600),($time/60%60), $time%60);
```

will be the best options to use ...

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/3534705/4342230, but adding days:

```
function durationToString($seconds) {
  $time = round($seconds);

  return sprintf(
    '%02dD:%02dH:%02dM:%02dS',
    $time / 86400,
    ($time / 3600) % 24,
    ($time / 60) % 60,
    $time % 60
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$time = 290.52262423327;
echo date("h:i:s", mktime(0,0, round($time) % (24*3600)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the most efficient way, but if you also need to display days, this works:

```
function foo($seconds) { 
$t = round($seconds); 
return sprintf('%02d  %02d:%02d:%02d', ($t/86400%24), ($t/3600) -(($t/86400%24)*24),($t/60%60), $t%60);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
private function conversionTempsEnHms($tempsEnSecondes)
    {
        $h = floor($tempsEnSecondes / 3600);
        $reste_secondes = $tempsEnSecondes - $h * 3600;

        $m = floor($reste_secondes / 60);
        $reste_secondes = $reste_secondes - $m * 60;

        $s = round($reste_secondes, 3); 
        $s = number_format($s, 3, '.', '');

        $h = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $m = str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $s = str_pad($s, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $temps = $h . ":" . $m . ":" . $s;

        return $temps;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, going off other peoples answers I made my own parser. 
Works with days, hours, minutes and seconds. And *should* be easy to expand to weeks/months etc.
It works with deserialisation to c# as well

```
function secondsToTimeInterval($seconds) {
    $t = round($seconds);
    $days = floor($t/86400);
    $day_sec = $days*86400;
    $hours = floor( ($t-$day_sec) / (60 * 60) );
    $hour_sec = $hours*3600;
    $minutes = floor((($t-$day_sec)-$hour_sec)/60);
    $min_sec = $minutes*60;
    $sec = (($t-$day_sec)-$hour_sec)-$min_sec;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d', $days, $hours, $minutes, $sec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple formatter with progressively added parts - sample:

- formatTime(123) => `2m 3s`
- formatTime(7400) => `2h 3m 20s`
- formatTime(999999) => `11d 13h 46m 39s`

---

```
function formatTime($secs)
{
    $secs = max(0, intval($secs));
    if($secs > 0){
        $out = [];
        $yrs = floor($secs / 31536e3);
        if($yrs){
            $out[] = $yrs."y";
        }
        $rem = $secs - $yrs * 31536e3;
        $days = floor($rem / 86400);
        if($days || $out){
            $out[] = $days."d";
        }
        $rem -= $days * 86400;
        $hrs = floor($rem / 3600);
        if($hrs || $out){
            $out[] = $hrs."h";
        }
        $rem -= $hrs * 3600;
        $min = floor($rem / 60);
        if($min || $out){
            $out[] = $min."m";
        }
        $rem -= $min * 60;
        $out[] = $rem."s";
        return implode(" ", $out);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
$newtime = sprintf( "%02d:%02d:%02d", $time / 3600, $time / 60 % 60, $time % 60 );
```

2)

```
$newsec = sprintf( "%.2f", $time );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Carbon (such as in Laravel), you can do this:

`$timeFormatted = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfDay()->addSeconds($seconds)->toTimeString();`

But `$timeFormatted = date("H:i:s", $seconds);` is probably good enough.

Just see [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534533/output-is-in-seconds-convert-to-hhmmss-format-in-php#comment68775474_24754138).

Answer (score 0):

Here was my implementation with microseconds

```php
    /**
     * @example 00 d 00 h 00 min 00 sec 005098 ms (0.005098 sec.ms)
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        // Add your code to get $seconds and $microseconds
        $time = round(($seconds + $microseconds), 6, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);

        return sprintf(
            '%02d d %02d h %02d min %02d sec %06d ms (%s sec.ms)',
            $time / 86400,
            ($time / 3600) % 24,
            ($time / 60) % 60,
            $time % 60,
            $time * 1000000 % 1000000,
            $time
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('H:i:s', round($time)%86400);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo date('H:i:s',$time);

echo number_format($time,2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Numero uno... http://www.ckorp.net/sec2time.php (use this function)

Numero duo... `echo round(290.52262423327,2);`

Comment: the link you posted is dead