# Formatting seconds to a readable format

Tags: php, date, format

I know about the `date` and `gmdate` functions, but my needs are different in this case.

I have a number of seconds which I need to convert to something like:

> A days B hours C minutes D seconds

I don't know how to format my seconds like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-php

Comment: There are detailed examples in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `floor` and the values `86400` (seconds in a day - `60 * 60 * 24`), `3600` (seconds in an hour - `60 * 60`) and `60` (seconds in a minute):

```
<?php
    function secondsToTime($seconds) {
        $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
        $seconds -= ($days * 86400);

        $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $seconds -= ($hours * 3600);

        $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
        $seconds -= ($minutes * 60);

        $values = array(
            'day'    => $days,
            'hour'   => $hours,
            'minute' => $minutes,
            'second' => $seconds
        );

        $parts = array();

        foreach ($values as $text => $value) {
            if ($value > 0) {
                $parts[] = $value . ' ' . $text . ($value > 1 ? 's' : '');
            }
        }

        return implode(' ', $parts);
    }

    var_dump(secondsToTime(1234561));
    //string(36) "14 days 6 hours 56 minutes 1 second"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/gxDPAtSJ)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with **[Date and Time extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)**:

#### Use example:

```php
echo secondsToTime(1234563);
# 14 days, 6 hours, 56 minutes and 3 seconds
```

**[Link to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/67332) + [Demo](https://eval.in/58780)**.