# converting seconds to HH:MM:SS in PHP

Tags: php

i have tried using gmdate to convert seconds into HH:MM:SS with this code:

```
gmdate("H:i:s", $result["s"]
```

`$result["s]` equals `142:000`

when i echo the gmdate code, it displays `00:24:02` which is wrong, it should be `00:02:36`

Comment: In terms of date or elapsed time?

Comment: Why is it `142:000`? `gmdate` take a timestamp, not seconds from nowhere.

Comment: its in terms of elapsed time

Comment: `142:000` = 142 is seconds? What is 000 part? Isn't 142 seconds = 2min:22sec, not 2min:36sec like you wrote?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://en.php.net/function.gmdate) and you will see, that `gmdate()` expects a unix timestamp, not some arbitrary seconds value you came up with.

Comment: It echos `00:02:22` for me, which is the correct output. (142 - 120 = 22 => 2:22) http://codepad.org/CkH8bwze

Comment: @TillHelge I agree but it will just assume 142 elapsed seconds from 1.1.1970 @ 00:00:00, which will output the correct time (as long as date isn't in the question)

Comment: @ChenAsraf where is the 120 coming from? 142 (or 142.000) seconds equals 2 minutes 36 seconds (142 / 60) - http://bit.ly/18Aozei - but its showing 00:02:22

Comment: 120 is 60 * 2 = 2 minutes. The remainder (22) is the remaining seconds

Comment: but 142 seconds in minutes is 02:36

Comment: check here http://bit.ly/18Aozei

Comment: @charliejsford: you link is correct, that is `2.36666` **MINUTES**, where do you see on that link `2min:36sec`? See my answer bellow for explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Where is the 120 coming from? 142 (or 142.000) seconds equals 2 minutes 36 seconds (142 / 60)

`142 / 60 = 2.36666667 minutes` which doesn't equals `2min 36sec`. `2.36666` is a decimal number, and it represents minutes. If you wish to format `2.36666` to minutes and seconds, then take the whole number as minutes, and `0.366666 * 60` as seconds, that is `22`, so result is `2min 22sec`.

---

You should cast 2nd parameter to integer, or at least remove `:000` part:

```
$result['s'] = '142:000';
echo gmdate("H:i:s", (int)$result['s']); # 0:02:22
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://3v4l.org/tQpQK)</kbd>

You will have problem, if you have more than 86400 seconds (1 day). In that case you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/67332).

Comment: `gmdate` seems to fix that problem on its own, it casts to int alone

Comment: @ChenAsraf: making code that generates notices is not best practice IMHO. [Demo](http://3v4l.org/0aomQ).

Comment: I agree, but point is that wasn't the problem in the specific case

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 685);
```

OR

```
days = seconds / ( 24 * 60 * 60 )
seconds -= ( days * ( 24 * 60 * 60 ) )

hours = seconds / ( 60 * 60 )
seconds -= ( hours * ( 60 * 60 ) )

minutes = seconds / 60
seconds -= ( minutes * 60 )
```

Comment: variables need "$" and you can use the modulus operator !

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Y0u can try this

```
$getHours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$getMins = floor(($seconds - ($getHours*3600)) / 60);
$getSecs = floor($seconds % 60);
echo $getHours.':'.$getMins.':'.$getSecs;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  Function format.  No leading zeros and unlimited hours, days not used.

```
 /* WHM MOD convert a string of seconds to H:M:S format */

function sec2hms($secs) {
    $secs = round($secs);
    $secs = abs($secs);
    $hours = floor($secs / 3600) . ':';
    if ($hours == '0:') $hours = '';
    $minutes = substr('00' . floor(($secs / 60) % 60), -2) . ':';
    $seconds = substr('00' . $secs % 60, -2);
return ltrim($hours . $minutes . $seconds, '0');
}
```