# Show ticks in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: php, date, monitoring, uptime, uptime-monitoring

I'm trying to show an UpTime in Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.
Something like *20 days*, *4 hours*, *9 minutes*, *3 seconds*

Here is my PHP Code:

```
// Get uptime with my SNMP class
$iTicks = $oHardwareMonitoring->fGetSystemUpTime();

// Convert Ticks to seconds
$iSecondes = $iTicks / 100;

// Convert seconds to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
$sSecondes = gmdate('s', $iSecondes);
$sMinutes  = ($sSecondes > 60 ? round(($sSecondes / 60), 0) : null);
$sHeures   = ($sMinutes > 60 ? round(($sMinutes / 60), 0) : null);
$sJours    = ($sHeures > 24 ? round(($sHeures / 24), 0) : null);

// Show the result
echo '<b>'.$sInfosUptime.'</b> : '.
($sJours != null ? $sJours.' '.DAY.' ' : null).
($sHeures != null ? $sHeures.' '.HOUR.' ' : null).
($sMinutes != null ? $sMinutes.' '.MINUTE.' ' : null).
$sSecondes.' '.SECONDE;
```

When I execute the PHP, I get **38 Seconde(s)** for **429859** ticks.

How to show the uptime correctly?

Comment: what is the expected Output?

Comment: Something like _20 days_, _4 hours_, _9 minutes_, _3 secondes_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sSecondes` can never be greater than 60 because you use `gmdate('s', $iSecondes);` which returns a value between 00 and 59. Therefore the conditions that follow will never be evaluated as `true`.

Using the following line:

```
$sMinutes = ($iSecondes > 60 ? round(($iSecondes / 60), 0) : null);
```

returns:

> 1 HOUR 72 MINUTE 38 SECONDE

Better but not exactly what is expected.

We can get the proper amount of each unit by using modulo, division and `floor()`:

```
$sSecondes = $iSecondes%60;
$sMinutes  = floor($iSecondes%3600/60);
$sHeures   = floor($iSecondes%86400/3600);
$sJours    = floor($iSecondes/86400);
```

Which returns:

> 1 HOUR 11 MINUTE 38 SECONDE

Comment: Heeeeell yeah ! Thank you dude ! It's working. I got _2 Heure(s) 4 Minute(s) 11 Seconde(s)_ for _745128 ticks_

Answer (score 0):

Out the top of my head - wasn't able to check the code as I don't have a webserver available immediately:

```
// Get uptime with my SNMP class
$iTicks = $oHardwareMonitoring->fGetSystemUpTime();

// Convert Ticks to secondes
$iSecondes = $iTicks / 100;

// Convert secondes to Days, Hours, Minutes, Secondes
$sSecondes = $iSecondes % 60;
$sMinutes = round($iSecondes / 60,0);
$sHeures = round($sMinutes / 60,0);
$sJours = round($sHeures / 24,0);



// Show the result
echo '<b>'.$sInfosUptime.'</b> : '.
($sJours != 0 ? $sJours.' '.DAY.' ' : null).
($sHeures != 0 ? $sHeures.' '.HOUR.' ' : null).
($sMinutes != 0 ? $sMinutes.' '.MINUTE.' ' : null).
$sSecondes.' '.SECONDE;
```

Comment: I got _2 Heure(s) 112 Minute(s) 57 Seconde(s)_ for _671728_ ticks :-/

Comment: Working on a solution in JS and then rewriting it in PHP, give me a moment. :)

Comment: I can do something like `$sMinutes >= 60 ? ($sMinutes > 60 ? $sMinutes - 60 : $sMinutes = 0) : $sMinutes)` but it's not a good way for me

Comment: Ok but I need to use vars to show the right text. I want to show *Days*, *Minutes*, etc ... in french, english, etc ... We must pay attention to this