# PHP Time Since Function Bug

Tags: php, mysql

i am writing a time since function to return the time since a given mysql datetime. When taking the $oldtime from current time() it is returning a negative int when i need a positive int. I have written similar functions before in other languages but i have become blind to this problem, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
function timeSince($time){
        $today = date("Y");
        $oldtime = strtotime($time);
        $time = time() - $oldtime;
        $tokens = array (
            3600 => 'h',
            60 => 'm',
            1 => 's'
        );

        if($time >= 86400){
        }
    }

echo timeSince('2016-02-25 14:35:00');
```

Comment: For me, your example should have a negative value for $time because it isn't 2:35pm on Feb 25, 2016 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` uses timezone in your PHP settings. Depending on timezone set, it might convert to the time that is yet to happen. For example, on my ukrainian server, `strtotime('2016-02-25 14:35:00')` converts to `1456403700`, on a server in another timezone (US/Pacific) it converts to `1456439700`.

Quote from PHP docs:

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.
>
> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default time zone.

You can add UTC/GMT offset to your datetime (1st param), for example  `strtotime('2016-02-25 14:35:00 +0800')` or `('2016-02-25 14:35:00 GMT+08:00')` will convert to `1456382100`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Igor, this may be the problem as i have used similar code before and not come across this problem. I will test it out and report back.

Answer (score 3):

it could be much more convenient if you use PHP's `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes and their methods:

```
function timeSince($datetime) {
    $now        = strtotime("now");
    $then       = strtotime($datetime);
    $dt_now     = new DateTime("@" . $now);
    $dt_then    = new DateTime("@" . $then);

    //DateTime's diff method returns a DateInterval object which got a format method:
    return $dt_now->diff($dt_then)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

some test cases:

```
//my local date & time is around "2016-02-25 19:49:00" when testing
echo '<pre>';

echo timeSince('2016-02-25 19:30:00');
//0 days, 0 hours, 19 minutes and 11 seconds
echo PHP_EOL;

echo timeSince('2013-11-02 15:43:12'); 
//845 days, 4 hours, 4 minutes and 3 seconds
echo PHP_EOL;

echo timeSince('2017-01-31 00:22:45'); 
//340 days, 4 hours, 35 minutes and 30 seconds
echo PHP_EOL;

echo timeSince('1950-05-14 07:10:05');
//24028 days, 12 hours, 37 minutes and 10 seconds
echo PHP_EOL;
```

*code partially based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/3391783*

Comment: Thanks for your help, although the answer to my specific problem was answered below i wanted to say that i agree with your comment, a much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `$oldtime` must be smaller value than current `time()`.

So, if you want to count time between larger value, simply reverse your equation:

This line:
`$time = time() - $oldtime;`

Becomes:
`$time = $oldtime - time();`

Comment: Or, use `abs($time()-$oldtime);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as far as i was aware time() would always return a larger number as it is the most recent,which is why i am having such a problem with it. I have seen it done similar to this in other stack queries. Is my thinking wrong? Cheers.