# Return difference in time using php

Tags: php

With the following line i get a DATE in Y-m-d format.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($result["created_at"]));
```

Its the creation date of an account. now id like to calculate how old the account is so i can print it out like  5 Years, 5 Months as a example.

any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635311/php-time-since-function-bug

Comment: Please do a search before asking a question. Lots of these simple question already have great answers, and they all show up on google

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: create a current date and use the difference.

```
$currentDate = new Date();
$interval = $currentDate->diff(new Date($result["created_at"]));
echo $interval->y . ' years and ' . $interval->m . ' months';
```