# time to month week and day convertion

Tags: php

I have issue when converting date to a left weeks, hours and months.

Here my code:

```
$time_elapsed   = time() - $createDate;
$hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
$days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
$weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
$months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
```

But when i display for example `$months`, i get: `565`

```
$createDate =1470165198; // Created with time(); 15 minutes ago
```

Supposed to show `0` no ? since there around 15 minutes difference between them.

Comment: 15 mins difference between what? Do you mean `$createDate` which you did not show us how you created?

Comment: Created with `time()` 15 minutes ago !!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. `$month` is 0. https://eval.in/616330

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: You have other issues in your code as well. You should go in descending order of time and if the time unit is greater than 0, subtract that many seconds from your elapsed time. Or you will end up with `12 months, 365 days...` because you are getting the time unit of the total time, not what is left after the previous unit was calculated.

Comment: And what is the solution ?

Comment: have a look at the question that @Spartan posted. It has multiple working solutions.

Comment: I didn't found my answer there, already made a search.

Answer (score 0):

$create_date must be an integer not string
thus

```
$createDate = 1470165198; // no quotes
```

Comment: There no quotes since it's fetched from database directly.

Comment: Ok, can you adjust this in your post?

Comment: php would also convert to an integer soon as you tried a math operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use of the PHP DateTime class it can be very easily done like this

```
$start = new DateTime('2015-08-01 00:00:00');  // instead of your time()
$end = new DateTime('2016-09-02 01:01:01');

$interval = $start->diff($end);

echo $interval->format('%y year %m Months %d Days %i Minutes %s Seconds');
```

RESULT:

```
+1 year +1 Month +1 Day +1 Minute +1 Second
```

Now if your required output is different you can play with the formatting as much as you like.

To initialize your a DateTime object using your `$createDate = time()` timestamp you can do :-

```
$start = new DateTime();
$start->setTimestamp($createDate);
$end = new DateTime('now');

$interval = $start->diff($end);
echo $interval->format('%y year %m Months %d Days %i Minutes %s Seconds');
```

> The [PHP DateTime Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)