# How to convert working hours to working days?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to display a number of hours in days and hours as a human readable string but I need that 1 day be equal to 7 hours, so a working day.

I found this solution, but based on 1 day equal to 24 hours :

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

source: [Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds)

Comment: DateTime won't help you as it assumes the day is between 23 and 25 hours long. You probably need to do your own thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime` won't help here. You need to count it on your own.

But this is simple math. Integer division for days and modulo for hours.

```
$hours = 12345;

$days = floor($hours/7);
$restHours = $hours%7;

echo "{$days} days, {$restHours} hours"; //1763 days, 4 hours
```

Comment: Also basic match to get from seconds to hours.

Comment: @JonStirling yes, but OP wrote `display a number of hours in days and hours`, so I assumed hours are input data although his funciton probably takes time in seconds as argument.

Comment: Thank you, I imagine that it was a problem of math but I could not do this simple calculation. I always forgot the use of modulo.

Answer (score 2):

Custom made code to deal with this (probably on of 1000 ways on can implement this, I don't claim this to be the best, or good or anything like that).

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
        $totalMinutes = intval($seconds / 60);
        $totalHours = intval($totalMinutes / 60);
        $totalDays = intval($totalHours / 7);
        echo "$totalDays days and ".($totalHours%7)." hours ".($totalMinutes%60)." minutes and ".($seconds%60)." seconds";             
}
```

e.g.

```
secondsToTime(8*60*60);
```

prints

> 1 days and 1 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds