# Change seconds ouput to minutes and hours

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I have a countdown system set up in my project where a user enters by hours how long they want to reserve something for. i.e)1,2,3,4 hours etc. Then a countdown timer starts and notifies them when it is done. I found a really good one online however it is giving the countdown only in relation to seconds remaining. I am wondering if anyone knows how to manipulate this code to show hrs:minutes remaining.

I already tried the w3schools one however that won't work as that is in terms of an actual given future time

```
        <!-- $_row["Time"] returns the number of hours hence must multiply by 3600 to get it in terms of seconds for this example to work -->
    <?php $remain= $_row["Time"] * 3600;  ?>



<script>
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Time Remaining "+secs+" seconds";
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Your Time is up!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<p>Please evacuate the parking space as soon as possible</p><br>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="Home.php">Return to Home</a>';
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>
<div id="status"></div>
<script>countDown(<?php echo $remain ?>,"status");</script>
```

Comment: Use DateTime. Scroll down a little on this page, there's a highly voted answer to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds/19680778#19680778

Comment: Hi @RussJ, that is a good idea however you loose the countdown functionality as that is just a static example

Comment: "I found a really good one online" - no you didn't. In fact you probably found the worst one imaginable. Passing a string to `setTimeout`? Relying on `setTimeout` to be precise? (hint: it's not nor is it ever specified to be). On top of that the "end" condition isn't even done right because it tries to clear the timeout *before* it gets set...

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

> "I found a really good one online" - no you didn't. In fact you probably found the worst one imaginable. Passing a string to `setTimeout`? Relying on `setTimeout` to be precise? (hint: it's not nor is it ever specified to be). On top of that the "end" condition isn't even done right because it tries to clear the timeout before it gets set...

Try something like this instead.

```
function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    var targetTime = Date.now() + secs*1000;
    var timer;

    function formatTime(secs) {
        var hours = Math.floor(secs/3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor(secs/60)%60;
        var seconds = secs%60;
        var pad = function(n) {return n<10 ? "0"+n : n;};
        return hours+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(seconds);
    }
    function tick() {
        var timeleft = Math.floor((targetTime - Date.now()) / 1000);
        element.innerHTML = "Time Remaining: "+formatTime(timeleft);
        if( timeleft < 0) {
            element.innerHTML = "Time up!";
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
   }

   timer = setInterval(tick, 200); // higher numbers are less precise
   tick(); // perform first update immediately
}
```

This uses actual timing to ensure the end time is when it's supposed to be!

Answer (score 0):

use code like this

```
<script>
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
 }

function countDown(secs,elem) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    var h=secondsToHms(secs);
    element.innerHTML = "Time Remaining "+h;
    if(secs < 1) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        element.innerHTML = '<h2>Your Time is up!</h2>';
        element.innerHTML += '<p>Please evacuate the parking space as soon as 
       possible</p><br>';
        element.innerHTML += '<a href="Home.php">Return to Home</a>';
    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);
}
</script>

<div id="status"></div>
<script>countDown(10,"status");</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @bob_1982 but can I ask how should I pass the $_row["Time"] (the number of hours) into it?

Comment: why you want to pass hours ? as in current code you are sending seconds and its being converted to hours,minutes and seconds

Comment: Like when I enter this code in it does nothing as I am not passing any value into it. I need to be converting the result of   <?php $remain= $_row["Time"] * 3600;  ?>

Comment: it works for me . i edited and its now full working code