# PHP Display Days, hours and minutes

Tags: php

i am trying to display 'Days' and 'hours' code is working fine, but issue is i don't want to show 0 days. if day= 0 then show only hours.

```
<?php
  $datetime1 = new DateTime();
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($feed['dt_date_added']);
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  $elapsed = $interval->format('%a days %h hours'); 
  echo $elapsed;
?>
```

Output : - 0 Days 5 Hour

Expected Output: 5 Hour

Comment: So check if hours is zero and then don't show it if it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds

Comment: really  ?  @JohnConde   i said  if day= 0 then show only hours.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I think you missed the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check whether the number of days is 0 or not, and adjust your output format accordingly. The DateInterval object provides the "d" property which lets you see the number of days (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)).

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime($feed['dt_date_added']);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$format = "%h hours";
if($interval->d > 0) $format = "%a days ".$format; //adjust the format according to the number of days
$elapsed = $interval->format($format); 
echo $elapsed;
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d01ae70566b1b4466664fcff8f7c70b261766c48

Answer (score 0):

You just have to check if the days are 0:

```
   $datetime1 = new DateTime();
   $datetime2 = new DateTime($feed['dt_date_added']);
   $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
   $elapsed = $interval->format( $interval->format('%a') ? '%a days %h hours' : '%h hours'  ); 
   echo $elapsed;
```