# PHP - convert seconds to months using only datetime

Tags: php

From [Convert seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds/41091196) we can get the good function of [User Galvic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/glavi%C4%87):

```
function secondsToTime($seconds){
    $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF -> diff($dtT) -> format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
    }

echo secondsToTime(3600 * 24 * 31);
```

and this work greath!, but I want add months, then I put **%m months** return 0, and **%M months** return two digits.

How to convert `3600 * 24 * 32` in [1 month and 2 day] and `3600 * 24 * 30 * 13` in [1 year and 1 month]?

Becosue in [Function of Galvic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds/41091196) exist many options, but only ONE using 2 lines: GALVIC function, then I want add to this two lines the option "months, year".

Thanks

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#115065

Answer (score 0):

Don't use %a for days, use %d instead.

```
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%y years, %m months, %d days');
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladan, ```secondsToTime(3600 * 24 * 31);``` return **1 month**; the months in PHP are of 31 days?

Comment: @Stackoverflow No, the trick is that we are measuring the difference between January 1st 1970 (@0) and February 1st 1970 (3600 * 24 * 31), so the difference is indeed 1 month. But try setting the start date to February 1st 1970 and compare it against March 2nd for example, you'd get [1 month and 1 day](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/663473ddc85e668a5aed5ee05a104b4324e0c7dd)