# Hide Unused/zero result from showing on format (Second to readable data format function)

Tags: php, function, date, format

Before i asking, i watched this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/11011981
the code that i used is this

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
$dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
$dtT = new \DateTime("@$seconds");
return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

but the problem was....if the data we use is "1640467" result is
18 days, 23 hours, 41 minutes and 7 seconds

but, my data isn't that big. sometimes it only "964" and if using that code. the result was
0 days, 0 hours, 16 minutes and 4 seconds

can i make it somehow it only show the format that has data on it? example if my result is
0 days, 0 hours, 16 minutes and 4 seconds
i want the empty 0 days, 0 hours to be hidden.... anyone know how to do it?

thanks... i stuck on this since this morning lol

Comment: Did you tried 2nd solution of the thread you provided : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59901330/4248328

Comment: https://3v4l.org/alRJk

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh ok wait i will test it

Comment: Ok thanks it works :)
now i found the answer

Comment: When you get any thread, then kindly test all given solution to see which one worked for you. The one worked for you, give them an upvote as well, so that good answers will show on top. If an answer is not voted/less voted that doesn't mean that it will not work for you.

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh sure, sorry again for this. :) i will remember it

Comment: It's ok, no need to say sorry.