# Convert milliseconds to minutes: Getting incorrect result

Tags: php

I have a total ammount of milliseconds (ie 4007587) and I want to display it as hours:minutes:seconds.

my PHP code:

```
$mil = 4007587
$timestamp = $mil/1000;
echo date("g:i:s", $timestamp);
```

the result should be **1:06:47** but my result is **8:06:47**
what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output is in seconds. convert to hh:mm:ss format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534533/output-is-in-seconds-convert-to-hhmmss-format-in-php)

Comment: Check your server timezone.

Comment: As a general rule when working with dates, ignore the old [date & time PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) and use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) **classes**. With a couple of exceptions, the old date&time functions do not work with timezones and handling multiple timezones with them is difficult. The classes work with timezones and each `DateTime` object knows the timezone of the date it stores. Working with them is easy and produces more readable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `date` takes account of your local timezone. Try using [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead:

```
$mil = 4007587;
$timestamp = $mil/1000;
// local timezone
echo date("g:i:s", $timestamp);
// UTC
echo gmdate("g:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Output

```
2:06:47
1:06:47
```