# How do I format an integer into a HH:MM:SS format?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm tracking the amount of total time each employee has spent at work from the moment of employment.

I have the entries table (Check in/Check Out), and the time gets calculated after the checkout happens.

However, I have the relevant column for that in integer format, and if FOR EXAMPLE someone enters at 10:53:07 and leaves at 11:18:31, it displays 24
as a result (since there's 24 seconds between 07 and 31). Basically resets back to 0 once it reaches 60.

Picture:

[image: Example]

Here's the relevant code I use in the controller for summation:

```
    $employees = Employee::all();


    $totals = [];

    foreach($employees as $employee)
    {
        $totals[$employee->id] = $employee->attendances->sum('time_spent_working');
    }
```

I formatted time_spent_working as an integer in the migration itself. What would be the best/cleanest solution here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output is in seconds. convert to hh:mm:ss format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534533/output-is-in-seconds-convert-to-hhmmss-format-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate this difference when needed using the [Carbon diffForHumans functionality](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) instead of saving this in the database.

Like so

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse($date->entered);
$endDate = Carbon::parse($date->left);

$diff = $startDate->diffInDays($endDate);
```

If you want an absolute number, instead of a human-readable one,  you could use Carbons `diffInSeconds` which gives the amount of seconds, even when it is more then 60. But then you'd have to have some logic to display seconds/minutes/hours etc.

Answer (score 0):

use diff function

```
$startTime = "2019-01-05 23:20:25";
 $start  = new Carbon($startTime);
  $finishTime = "2019-01-06 01:20:30";
  $end    = new Carbon($finishTime);
$end->diff($start)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: Gives me an error:

Call to a member function format() on int

Comment: take you start date and end date and pass it to the function as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it via the gmdate function (Inserted this into the view)

```
<td>{{ gmdate("H:i:s", $totals[$employee->id]) }}</td>
```

If it helps, I've been storing the diff in time in SECODNS

From the controller:

```
$attendance->time_spent_working = $attendance->checked_out_at->diffInSeconds($attendance->checked_in_at);
```