# Converting Seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I found a function to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS online, the function is this:

```
function sec2hms ($sec, $padHours = false) {
$hms = "";
$hours = intval(intval($sec) / 3600);
$hms .= ($padHours)
? str_pad($hours, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':'
: $hours. ':';
$minutes = intval(($sec / 60) % 60);
$hms .= str_pad($minutes, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT). ':';
$seconds = intval($sec % 60);
$hms .= str_pad($seconds, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
return $hms;
}
```

I know this works fine as if I do `echo(sec2hms(3600));` it will return as `1:00:00`

What I want to happen is to use that function to convert every single entry in the column `timeran` and then display it in a HTML table with the columns `username` and `score`, I am not sure how to do this so if someone could help me out then that'd be great. I am currently using the code below to display the table but that only shows time taken in seconds and I would like it to be in HH:MM:SS:

```
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Time Taken (s)</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gamescores ORDER BY Time DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
for($rank=1; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $rank++) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>{$rank}</td>
    <td>{$row['username']}</td>
    <td>{$row['timetaken']}</td>
    <td>{$row['score']}</td>
```

If there is a better way of converting seconds to HH:MM:SS then that would be great too.

Comment: You could consider changing the column to be of `TIME` type. You would still need to convert when storing the data, but it might make reporting easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870843/67332)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the MySQL SEC_TO_TIME function.

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(2378);
        -> '00:39:38'
```

So you can write your SQL query as:

```
SELECT username, score, SEC_TO_TIME(timeran) as timetaken FROM gamescores ORDER BY Time DESC
```

Your code then becomes:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, score, SEC_TO_TIME(timeran) as timetaken FROM gamescores ORDER BY Time DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
for($rank=1; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $rank++) {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>{$rank}</td>
    <td>{$row['username']}</td>
    <td>{$row['timetaken']}</td>
    <td>{$row['score']}</td>
```

Comment: @JJ I had tried that previously and that didn't return what I wanted, it returned `Resource ID #8`

Comment: I will try what you just edited your post with, thanks.

Comment: Just managed to get it working, thank you, that does work faster then the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your output with the function. Put this code in the appropriate place.

```
echo "<td>". sec2hms($row['timetaken']) . "</td>";
```

Comment: This works, but if you can make SEC_TO_TIME work, it will run much faster than this solution, especially for large datasets.

Comment: Agreed, but it was good for him to learn how to do it this way as well. Jamie, please mark an answer as accepted if it is correct - welcome to S.O.