# Convert number of minutes into hours & minutes using PHP

Tags: php, time

I have a variable called `$final_time_saving` which is just a number of minutes, 250 for example.

How can I convert that number of minutes into hours and minutes using PHP in this format:

`4 hours 10 minutes`

Comment: Is this number the minute count? 250min != 4h 17min

Comment: No, but Googling 250 minutes in hours returns 4.16666667 hours, so maybe that's where Rob got the figure from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
<?php

function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
    if ($time < 1) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($time / 60);
    $minutes = ($time % 60);
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}

echo convertToHoursMins(250, '%02d hours %02d minutes'); // should output 4 hours 17 minutes
```

Comment: The comment after the code is funny.. Copied from the question... 250 minutes is 4 hours (240 minutes) and 10 minutes, not 17 :)

Comment: It is indeed. Not sure why I wrote that! Leaving it in for posterity :)

Comment: It'd be nice if this would only return the minutes when hours=0.

Comment: @timpeterson That’s easy enough to implement.

Comment: @MartinBean Thanks I realize this. I was talking about adding the code to this example.

Comment: @timpeterson I think that’s outside the scope of this answer. The above isn’t meant to be a, use-in-every-situation helper. The OP can account for zero values if they need to; the above should be enough to get them started.

Comment: It might help to change the format to `'%d:%02d'`, since a string like "6:1" doesn't make as much sense as "6:01" for example.

Comment: And what about days?)

Comment: I would also like to know the code for showing just outputting hrs (if mins=0) e.g. 2hrs, or just mins (if hours=0) e.g. 45mins. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 124):

```
echo date('H:i', mktime(0,257));
```

Comment: best sollution!
also, for seconds => date('H\hi\m:s\s', mktime(0,0,$totalSeconds))

Comment: Wrong solution. Doesn't work for times > 24 hours and also depends on timezone configuration. It's not a *date* you're working with, don't use `date` functions.

Comment: It is a solution to the _question_ but you're correct, @deceze , it isn't accurate with periods longer than 24h. I don't see how this is timezone-dependant, though. Rather; `gmmktime` would return a locally-offset time.

Comment: Admittedly, if you write code exactly like this, timezones probably won't affect it. However, it's easy to introduce bugs due to timezone shenanigans: http://3v4l.org/oH4ao

Comment: Perfect when you just need to convert some integers and you stay within the 24 hour boundary!

Comment: How can I make this work with seconds? I tried following date('H:i:s').. but that did not work any idea?

Comment: It's a misleading solution, should at least be noted that this doesn't work for > 24 hours.

Comment: Yep this bit me in the butt when we had a time > 24 hours. Dont use this.

Answer (score 50):

```
$hours = floor($final_time_saving / 60);
$minutes = $final_time_saving % 60;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve this with [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) extension, which will also work for number of minutes that is larger than one day (`>= 1440`):

```php
$minutes = 250;
$zero    = new DateTime('@0');
$offset  = new DateTime('@' . $minutes * 60);
$diff    = $zero->diff($offset);
echo $diff->format('%a Days, %h Hours, %i Minutes');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/104266)</kbd>

Comment: This breaks if you have minutes as something like `12.99`

Comment: Decimal is not a valid minute format. The question is "Convert number of minutes into hours & minutes using PHP".

Answer (score 9):

@Martin Bean's answer is perfectly correct but in my point of view it needs some refactoring to fit what a regular user would expect from a website (web system).
I think that when minutes are below 10 a leading zero must be added.
ex: 10:01, not 10:1

I changed code to accept `$time = 0` since 0:00 is better than 24:00.

One more thing - there is no case when `$time` is bigger than 1439 - which is 23:59 and next value is simply 0:00.

```
function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%d:%s') {
    settype($time, 'integer');
    if ($time < 0 || $time >= 1440) {
        return;
    }
    $hours = floor($time/60);
    $minutes = $time%60;
    if ($minutes < 10) {
        $minutes = '0' . $minutes;
    }
    return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

Comment: Good point, I agree the minutes need a leading zero. Another way you could do it would be to use the padding functionality of sprintf: `echo sprintf('%02d', 2);  // this echos "02"`

Comment: same as minutes, i added it for hours, specially important when adding to database so mysql won't get confused

Comment: the return value it's not consistent, may return void, may return string

Answer (score 8):

```
$t = 250;
$h = floor($t/60) ? floor($t/60) .' hours' : '';
$m = $t%60 ? $t%60 .' minutes' : '';
echo $h && $m ? $h.' and '.$m : $h.$m;
```

4 hours and 10 minutes

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for bringing up an old topic, but I used some code from one of these answers a lot, and today I told myself I could do it without stealing someone's code. I was surprised how easy it was. What I wanted is 510 minutes to be return as 08:30, so this is what the code does.

```
function tm($nm, $lZ = true){ //tm = to military (time), lZ = leading zero (if true it returns 510 as 08:30, if false 8:30
  $mins = $nm % 60;
  if($mins == 0)    $mins = "0$mins"; //adds a zero, so it doesn't return 08:0, but 08:00

  $hour = floor($nm / 60);

  if($lZ){
    if($hour < 10) return "0$hour:$mins";
  }

  return "$hour:$mins";
}
```

I use short variable names because I'm going to use the function a lot, and I'm lazy.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is :

```
    gmdate('H:i', $numberOfSeconds * 60)
```

Comment: >>> gmdate('H:i', 9999 * 60)
=> "22:39"
>>> gmdate('H:i', 99999 * 60)
=> "10:39"

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you want to something like:

```
echo date('G \h\o\u\r\s i \m\i\n\u\t\e\s', mktime(0, 90)); //will return 1 hours 30 minutes
echo date('G \j\a\m i \m\e\n\i\t', mktime(0, 90)); //will return 1 jam 30 menit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hour_min($minutes){// Total
   if($minutes <= 0) return '00 Hours 00 Minutes';
else    
   return sprintf("%02d",floor($minutes / 60)).' Hours '.sprintf("%02d",str_pad(($minutes % 60), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)). " Minutes";
}
echo hour_min(250); //Function Call will return value : 04 Hours 10 Minutes
```

Comment: Great idea, I took the concept and built on top of it. Thank for sharing

Answer (score 1):

```
$m = 250;

$extraIntH = intval($m/60);

$extraIntHs = ($m/60);             // float value   

$whole = floor($extraIntHs);      //  return int value 1

$fraction = $extraIntHs - $whole; // Total - int = . decimal value

$extraIntHss =  ($fraction*60); 

$TotalHoursAndMinutesString  =  $extraIntH."h ".$extraIntHss."m";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Martin_Bean and @Mihail Velikov answers. I just took their answer snippet and added some modifications to check,

1. If only Hours only available and minutes value empty, then it will display only hours.
2. Same if only Minutes only available and hours value empty, then it will display only minutes.
3. If minutes = 60, then it will display as 1 hour. Same if minute = 1, the output will be 1 minute.

Changes and edits are welcomed.
Thanks. Here is the code.

```
function convertToHoursMins($time) {
            
            $hours    = floor($time / 60);
            $minutes  = ($time % 60);

        
            if($minutes == 0){

                if($hours == 1){

                    $output_format = '%02d hour ';

                }else{

                    $output_format = '%02d hours ';
                }

                
                $hoursToMinutes = sprintf($output_format, $hours);

            }else if($hours == 0){

                if ($minutes < 10) {
                        $minutes = '0' . $minutes;
                }

                if($minutes == 1){

                    $output_format  = ' %02d minute ';

                }else{

                    $output_format  = ' %02d minutes ';
                }
                
                $hoursToMinutes = sprintf($output_format,  $minutes);

            }else {

                if($hours == 1){

                    $output_format = '%02d hour %02d minutes';

                }else{

                    $output_format = '%02d hours %02d minutes';
                }
                
                $hoursToMinutes = sprintf($output_format, $hours, $minutes);
            }
            
            return $hoursToMinutes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 answer using Carbon**

```
Carbon::createFromTime(
intdiv($final_time_saving, 60), 
($final_time_saving % 60), 
0, 
0)
->format('H:i')
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score -1):

> check this link for better solution. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975664/how-to-convert-hhmmss-to-minutes/59783258#59783258)
>
> [How to convert hh:mm:ss to minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975664/how-to-convert-hhmmss-to-minutes/59783258#59783258)

```
$minutes=$item['time_diff'];
$hours =   sprintf('%02d',intdiv($minutes, 60)) .':'. ( sprintf('%02d',$minutes % 60));
```