# Distance between postcodes code in full - But how can I have just 1 decimal place in distance?

Tags: php, postal-code

I have an amazing piece of code that works out the distance between 2 postcodes in both; distance (miles), and driving time.

The trouble now being - I am getting the distance in a very long form (eg: 10.2454014 miles)
**I just want it to just have 1 decimal place (eg 10.2 miles).**

Also, if it's not too difficult - when running the above code as is, you will notice that driving time is 80 minutes. Well that's just silly. **Does anyone know how to make it say the time in hours if over 60 minutes, and minutes if under 60?**

Amazing if anyone can help - This code is really useful for people!

```
<?php
        function get_driving_information($start, $finish, $raw = false)
{
    if(strcmp($start, $finish) == 0)
    {
        $time = 0;
        if($raw)
        {
            $time .= ' seconds';
        }

        return array('distance' => 0, 'time' => $time);
    }

    $start  = urlencode($start);
    $finish = urlencode($finish);

    $distance   = 'unknown';
    $time       = 'unknown';

    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$finish.'&sensor=false';
    if($data = file_get_contents($url))
    {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

        if(isset($xml->route->leg->duration->value) AND (int)$xml->route->leg->duration->value > 0)
        {
            if($raw)
            {
                $distance = (string)$xml->route->leg->distance->text;
                $time     = (string)$xml->route->leg->duration->text;
            }
            else
            {
                $distance = (int)$xml->route->leg->distance->value / 1000 / 1.609344;
                $time     = (int)$xml->route->leg->duration->value/ 60;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Could not find that route');
        }

        return array('distance' => $distance, 'time' => $time);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Could not resolve URL');
    }
}

try
{
    $info = get_driving_information('fy1 4bj', 'ls1 5ns');
    echo $info['distance'].' miles ' . 'That\'s about ' .$info['time'].' minutes drive from you';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/sprintf http://php.net/number_format

Comment: What kinds of things have you tried to do this?

Comment: I had tried this 'number_format' in the upper part of the coding, but after reading the first response I've realised I should have put it in the content being output!
 I just need to know how to distinguish between hours and minutes now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **number_format()** to format decimal/float values to desired decimal points. Use **gmdate()** function to convert time (*in seconds*) to formatted value like: Hours:Mins:Sec

```
// Format Distance
$info['distance'] = number_format($info['distance'], 2);

// Format time
$info['time'] = gmdate('H:i:s', ($info['time'] * 60));

// Output
echo $info['distance'] .' miles ' . 'That\'s about ' .$info['time'].' minutes drive from you';
```

Comment: That worked, I had been putting number_format in the coding at the top, not in what I was echoing. Just need to determine hours and minutes now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as rounding goes, just do this:

```
echo round($info['distance'], 1) . ' miles '
```

For your 80 minutes -> 1 hour 20 minutes, see this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8563576/2812842