# Convert minutes to time 'h:m:s'

Tags: php, codeigniter, time, converters, minute

I wonder if there is a function in php or codeigniter which can do this :

```
function transformTime($min)
{
    $min=(int)$min;
    $heure=(int)($min/60);
    $minute=(($min/60)-$heure)*60;


    return $heure .':' . $minute . ':00'; 
}
```

I want convert x minutes to a time format.

Comment: Why do you wonder if there is a function in PHP that does what you already have a function for?

Comment: Perhaps it can be more optimized ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563535/convert-number-into-hours-minutes-using-php?answertab=votes#tab-top, I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
<?php

function transformTime($min)
{
$ctime = DateTime::createFromFormat('i', $min);
$ntime= $ctime->format('H:i:s');
return $ntime;
}

echo transformTime(60); // "Prints" 01:00:00
```

Comment: It seems i can't use DateTime .. Do i need include something ?

Comment: Nope nothing ought to be included. This is shipped with PHP. Version supported is PHP 5 >= 5.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just format the output with [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/function.sprintf.php) or [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/function.str-pad.php):

```php
function transformTime($min)
{
    $hour = floor($min / 60);
    $min -= $hour * 60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', $hour, $min);
}
```