# How to convert hh:mm:ss to minutes

Tags: php

I have a time column `$data['Time'] (hh:mm:ss)` and I need to convert it to minutes. How can I do this? When I am writing like this:

```
$avg = ($data['Kilometers'] / $data['Time']) * 60;
```

I have this error

```
Warning: Division by zero in ... on line ..
```

Answer (score 15):

Try sometthin like this :

```
function minutes($time){
$time = explode(':', $time);
return ($time[0]*60) + ($time[1]) + ($time[2]/60);
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://codepad.org/v58Q5GUy)

Answer (score 8):

```
$time    = explode(':', $data['Time']);
$minutes = ($time[0] * 60.0 + $time[1] * 1.0);
$avg     = $minutes > 0 ? $data['Kilometers'] / $minutes : 'inf'; // if time stored is 0, then average is infinite.
```

Another way to convert the timestamp to minutes is,

```
$time    = date('i', strtotime($data['Time']));
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I edit the number of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: If I write like this 

$numberFormat = number_format($avs, 2, '.', '');

I have instead of - 'inf' I have 0.00

Comment: you can write like, `if($avg != 'inf') numberFormat = number_format($avs, 2, '.', '');`

Comment: Why it calculates without seconds?

Comment: @eek: in a valid timestamp, we can assume second will be less than 60. So I didn't added that. But the second approach already handles that

Comment: You mean this approach $time    = date('i', strtotime($data['Time'])); ?

Comment: $minutes = ($time[0] * 60.0 + $time[1] * 1.0);

As I understand. First $time is a hours, second $time is a minutes and I can add $time[2] as a seconds?

Comment: yes `$time[2]` represents number of seconds. If you need to add that, please add like, `$time[2]/60` to ensure you convert that to minute

Comment: Thanks a lot. I make like this - $minutes = ($timeAvs[0] * 60.0 + $timeAvs[1] + ($timeAvs[2] / 60) * 1.0);

Comment: date('i', strtotime('01:30')) == 30

Answer (score 2):

This is simple calculation use this one

```
    $time='01:02:10';
    $timesplit=explode(':',$time);
    $min=($timesplit[0]*60)+($timesplit[1])+($timesplit[2]>30?1:0);
    echo $min.' Min'  // 62 Min
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use following function 

<?php

function date2min ($hms) {

    $fromTime = strtotime($hms);

    $getMins = round(abs($fromTime) / 60,2);

    return $getMins;
}


$date   = date('H:i:s');  // $data['Time'] your desired time
$myResult = date2min($date);

and then use $myResult value according to your need.

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If hh:mm:ss is a string you can try this which is tested and it works:

```
 $hour=substr($string, 0,1);// we get the first two values from the hh:mm:ss string
 $hour=(int)$hour;
 $hourtomin=$hour*60;// after we have the hour we multiply by 60 to get the min
 $min=substr($string, 3,4);//now we do a substring 3 to 4 because we want to get only the min, and we don't want to get the : which is in position 2
 $min=(int)$min;
    
 $totalmin=$hourtomin+$min;// we just do a simple sum to calculate all the min
 echo $totalmin;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hourMinute2Minutes($strHourMinute) {
    $from = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $to = date('Y-m-d '.$strHourMinute.':00');
    $diff = strtotime($to) - strtotime($from);
    $minutes = $diff / 60;
    return (int) $minutes;
}

echo hourMinute2Minutes('01:30'); // returns 90
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing with StackOverflow! While showing the solution as code really helps, it would be more helpful if you can include some explanation on how it works and what is the cause of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this very simple way.

```
$minutes=$item['time_diff'];
$hours =   sprintf('%02d',intdiv($minutes, 60)) .':'. ( sprintf('%02d',$minutes % 60));
return $hours;
```

> Output will
>      **09:10**