# PHP - Convert this into hours

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I wanted to convert this into hours:

```
 <?php
( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 60 (This is for minutes)
?>
```

Comment: That's just math, is that too much for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert minutes to hour using following function:

```
<?php

function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
   if ($time < 1) {
      return;
   }
   $hours = floor($time / 60);
   $minutes = ($time % 60);
   return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}

echo convertToHoursMins(250, '%02d hours %02d minutes');
```

For more info check  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563535/convert-number-of-minutes-into-hours-minutes-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I understand you right, here's an example:

```
    <?php

        $resultM = ( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 60;           // (This is for minutes)
        $resultH = ( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 3600;         // (This is for hours)
        $resultH1 = floor(( strtotime('12:45:00') - strtotime('11:00:00') ) / 3600); // (This is for hours)

        echo "Minutes=$resultM<br />Hours(float)=$resultH<br />Houres(floor)=$resultH1<br />";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. Positive and Negative answer will depends on date provided first in `date_diff` function.

```
$date1 = date_create("12:45:00");
$date2 = date_create("11:00:00");

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo "Difference in Hours\n";
echo $diff->format("%R%H hours")."\n";
echo "Difference in Minutes\n";
echo $diff->format("%R%i minutes");
```

click here for [Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/1vrjn)

Another Example

```
$date2 = new DateTime("12:45:00");
$date1 = new DateTime("11:00:00");

echo "\n\n".$date2->diff($date1)->format("%H hours %i minutes");
```