# php convert seconds to timestamp

Tags: php, time

I have a total seconds value in my table but I would like to get a time format like `hh:mm:ss`,
currently I have for example: `seconds - 226` and I know that should be in time format 4 minutes and 26 seconds, but I've tried this code:

```
$seconds = 226;
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) / 60); 
$secs = floor(($seconds - ($hours*3600)) - ($mins*60));
```

and this outputs `3:46`

maybe there's something wrong with the formula?

EDIT: I got this value from a youtube scripts that returns duration of video:

```
    $ytvidid = $url;
$ytdataurl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/". $ytvidid;
$feedURL = $ytdataurl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feedURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get the result of http query
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// feed the curl output to simplexml_load_string
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($output) or die("XML string not loading");

//$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$media = $sxml->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
// get <yt:duration> node for video length
$yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
    echo $attrs['seconds'];
```

Comment: I dont believe as -- 4*60 +26 != 226

Comment: I just added how I got the seconds amount that's how I'm comparing the values, so the seconds it gives me I want to convert it back to real time

Comment: I did not understand what that has to do with mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [gmdate function](https://www.php.net/gmdate), you can view the format codes at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
```

---

PS. Your method already works. 226 seconds would be 3 minutes and 46 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

u can use this one.. this code like youtube time

```
$total_secs = '15454';

//time settings
$hours = floor($total_secs / 3600);
$mins = floor(($total_secs - ($hours*3600)) / 60);
$secs = floor($total_secs % 60);

//if hours zero, give for nothing like that (45:05)     
if ($hours<1) { $hours = ''; } else { $hours = $hours.':'; }
if ($mins<10) { $mins = '0'.$mins.':'; } else { $mins = $mins.':'; }
if ($secs<10) { $secs = '0'.$secs; } else { $secs = $secs; }

echo $output = $hours.$mins.$secs; //
```

Answer (score 0):

Supericy answer is good, but only works for 24 hours and if you need hours > day then I got something like:

```
$diffInSeconds = 64;
$h =  floor($diffInSeconds / 3600);
$m =  floor(($diffInSeconds - ($h * 3600)) / 60);
$s =  floor(($diffInSeconds - (($h * 3600) + $m * 60)));

echo sprintf('%02d', $h) . ":" . sprintf('%02d', $m). ":" . sprintf('%02d', $s);
```

BTW your calculation is fine. But I choose this way.