# calculate the sum of an array of hours and minutes php

Tags: php

Struggling with this!

I need a sum of all the diffs in php so here's the source

```
$du = mysql_query("select SUBTIME(timeto,timefrom) as diff from table");

while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($du))
{

    $total[] = strtotime($d["diff"]);

}

$t = array_sum($total);

echo gmdate("H:i", $t);
```

Before you say it...  I know I should be using PDO or mysqli

Unfortunately I need the solution in PHP

Comment: How about using mysql TIMEDIFF()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$du = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeto, timefrom))) AS TOTAL_SEC FROM table");

$d = mysql_fetch_assoc($du);

echo gmdate("H:i", $d["TOTAL_SEC"]);
```

Comment: Thanks - I do need it in PHP I'll edit the OP

Comment: that was quick! thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome... please, remember to rate answer...

Comment: gmdate didn't work so I used solution 2 here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond