# how to change seconds into Hour:minute:second in php

Tags: php

I have an android application that call services to upload image to server. I need to convert the time in seconds that i uploaded to the php side into `Hour:Minute:Second` format. Since I ma totally new to php, I need some help to achieve that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its simple..
use `gmdate("H :i :s",$time );`

Comment: @AlexChengalan: You could've got the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond) with a little bit of searching.

Comment: Question marked as duplicate and answer is also duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = 654654; //time in seconds.

$hours = intval($time / 3600);
$minutes = intval(($time - 3600 * $hours)/60);
$seconds = $time % 60;
```