# Why hour showing wrong after strtotime() conversion

Tags: php

i use  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond) url for time to minutes conversion but extra hour are shown where there is no hour in time.

my code is

```
<?php

$seconds=strtotime('00:11:10').'<br/>';
echo gmdate('H:i:s',$seconds).'<br/>';
$H = floor(($seconds / 3600));
$i = ($seconds / 60) % 60;


$s = $seconds % 60;
echo sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $H, $i, $s);

?>
```

the output showing 389496:11:10 //it should 00:11:10
what the problem is...??
I really getting pain on this any help would be appreciated .

Comment: strtotime is converting to number of seconds since January 1 1970! Put `echo "{$seconds}<br />";` as a second line so then you will see that it's a bigger number than you think.

Comment: Why do you want to process 00:11:10 and print out 00:11:10 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is [the snippet](http://ideone.com/pu3hT0) I use for `HH:MM:SS` to minutes conversion.

```
<?php

$str_time = "00:11:10";

$str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);

sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;

$minutes = $time_seconds / 60;

echo $minutes;
```

The output, as you expect, is `11.166666666667`.

If the time is `1 hour, 20 minutes and 10 seconds`, the output is then: `80.166666666667`

Answer (score -1):

I'd venture to say because you append `<br>` to the $seconds, and then use it with math functions like $seconds/3600 ... etc .. remove the `<br>` and add it later, or remove the `<br>` altogether

```
$seconds=strtotime('00:11:10');
echo gmdate('H:i:s',$seconds).'<br/>';
$H = floor(($seconds / 3600));
$i = ($seconds / 60) % 60;
$s = $seconds % 60;
echo sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $H, $i, $s);
```