# Timer is counting 1 hour more

Tags: php, time

I'm using a simple way to get a timer from the last action until now, with a cooldown to avoid exploit over a system I am programming.

I am using this formula:

```
$last_blood = $userRow['lastblood'];
$now_blood = time();
$cooldown_blood = 10800;
$timer_blood = $now_blood - $last_blood;
$next_blood = $cooldown_blood - $timer_blood;
$hours_blood = date("H:i:s", $next_blood);
```

The thing is that with 60M frame this cooldown system works like a charm, but this time I set it up to 10800 seconds (3 hours).

The `$hours_blood` keeps stating that I need to wait 1 more hour than the expected.

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Please ignore the Last "m" and "s" they are Typos over the config.

Comment: you should use [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) or use `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`

Comment: please elaborate. gmdate() instead of date() works like a charm add a answer so i can upvote you!
However i would love to understand Why!

Comment: date function uses local timezone to offset your timestamp, where gmdate uses Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)

Comment: Thanks @bansi i guess i can understand now

Comment: you get better idea with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Comment: Personally I use `date_default_timezone_set("UTC")` because screw timezones.