# Laravel Carbon: Convert seconds into HH:MM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Problem:

```
$tracked_time = 994554
```

In the laravel blade view, I want this to display as `77h 55m`

I tried to find a few solutions

```
{{ Carbon\CarbonInterval::seconds($duration['tracked_time'])->cascade()->forHumans()  ?? '' }}
```

it displays days and seconds, along with spelling it out.

```
1 day 7 hours 53 minutes 25 seconds
```

I also found

```
gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
```

But that doesn't work when its more than 1 day of seconds.

I tried to use the `->format('H:i:s')` on it but it just broke it.

I think the proper way would be format this in the Model with something like

```
public function timeTrackedForHumans()
{
 return $this->time_tracked->dosometing();

}
```

So that I could call it like `$task->timeTrackedForHumans`

Any advice is much appreciated. Is this something that always goes into Model or is it fine to also include it in the blade? Or if anyone knows what I can search for to find like a bunch of examples of how to do these types of formatting functions in the models.

I know this is a big ask and prob a super novice one, but genuinely am lost with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: convert seconds to minutes and hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960906/php-convert-seconds-to-minutes-and-hours)

Comment: ooh I will try that in the model, maybe that will work!

Comment: Yea idk what im doing, i got `App\Models\Task::timeTrackedForHumans must return a relationship instance.` when i tried to retun a s tring

Comment: public function timeTrackedForHumans()
    {
        $seconds = '555';

        return $seconds;
    }

Comment: I'm too embarrassed to formulate that as an answer: $hours = (int)($tracked_time/3600);
$minutes = (int)($tracked_time%3600/60);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working in the blade with

```
{{ sprintf('%dh %dm', $task->time_tracked_in_seconds / 3600, floor($task->time_tracked_in_seconds / 60) % 60) }}
```