# PHP Convert seconds into seconds, minutes, hours with hours exceeding 24

Tags: php, datetime

I want to convert seconds into seconds, minutes, then hours, and anything longer than 24 hours should include the total number of hours. Currently I have

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%hH %iM %ss');
}
```

But when I use

```
secondsToTime(90000)
```

I get:

```
1H 00M 00S
```

Instead, it should say

```
25H 00M 00S
```

I understand that it is technically correct, but how do I get days/weeks/months to convert into hours?

Comment: Just multiply all days by 24 and you get them in hours; See; http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days

Comment: Divide $seconds by 3600 and round down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `DateTime`, just simple arithmetic.

```
$h = floor($seconds / 3600);
$m = floor(($seconds % 3600) / 60);
$s = $seconds % 60;
return sprintf("%dH %02dM %02dS", $h, $m, $s);
```