# Generated option select time does not save properly

Tags: php

I have code that generates a select dropdown with times from 8:00am-6:00pm.  Upon selecting an option, and saving the form, the times are saved in the database properly.  HOWEVER, I cannot retrieve the times automatically.  This is my code so far :

```
<select value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>" name="data[InvoiceTime][<?php echo $key;?>][starttime]" id="starttime_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <?php
        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        for ($i = 28800; $i < 42600; $i += 900) {  // 1800 = half hour, 86400 = one day
        printf('<option value="%1$sam">%1$sam</option>',
        date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
        }
        for ($i = 43200; $i < 65000; $i += 900) {  // 12pm-6pm
        printf('<option value="%1$spm">%1$spm</option>',
        date('g:i', $time + $i), date('g:i a', $time + $i + 1800));
        }
        ?>
    </select>

Desired output : select "9:00am" and save form 9:00am is saved to db(which happens) reload form  9:00 appears preselected due to data saved in db

Actual output : select "9:00am" and save form 9:00am is saved to db reload form 8:00am appears(default value)
```

The following code works, but does not generate the option values :

```
<select value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>" name="data[InvoiceTime][<?php echo $key;?>][starttime]" id="starttime_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="8:00am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '8:00am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8:00am</option>
        <option value="9:00am" <?= ($item['starttime']) == '9:00am' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9:00am</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to move your check for the value into the existing code.

However, I have simplified your code quite a bit; I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with your `printf()` statements. [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate) is [happy to work with just seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172358/1255289) (you don't want to use `date()` as it can deliver unexpected results, based on your current time zone.) If an `<option>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute, the contents are used instead, so I've removed it. You should always always separate your PHP from your HTML (ideally more than I've done here, but this is a start.)

And in case you aren't familiar with them, here is some info on the [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and [heredoc blocks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
<?php
$start    = 28800;
$stop     = 65000;
$interval = 900;
$options  = "";
for ($seconds = $start; $seconds <= $stop; $seconds += $interval) {
    $time     = gmdate("g:ia", $seconds);
    $selected = ($item["starttime"] === $time) ? " selected" : "";
    $options .= sprintf("<option %s>%s</option>", $selected, $time);
}

echo <<< HTML
<select value="$starttime" name="data[InvoiceTime][$key][starttime]" id="starttime_$key" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
$options
</select>
HTML;
```