# MySQL total login hours become negative in the afternoon

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I'm storing users total login hours which I achieve by first storing the login time during the login and then on logout I store the time_out. Then to find total login hours, I use the following code. It all looked fine during the morning hours but now in the afternoon, the total count and time becomes negative.

Here is my `login.php` code which stores the first login details to hours table:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$chk = date("Y-m-d");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."' AND member_name = '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_NAME']."' AND time_in LIKE '%".$chk."%'");
$dt = date("Y-m-d");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == '0'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO hours (member_id, member_name, team, time_in) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['MEMBER_ID']."', '".$_SESSION['LOGIN_NAME']."', '".$_SESSION['TEAM']."', '".$dt."')");
}
```

now the logout.php so update time on logout

```
$id = $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$dt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");  
$max = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(hours_id) FROM hours WHERE member_id = '".$id."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($max);
$sql = "UPDATE hours SET time_out = '".$dt."' WHERE hours_id = '".$row[0]."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And here is how I check a users total login hours for the day or entire month:

```
<?php 

$query = "select member_id, member_name, team, time_in, time_out, sec_to_time(unix_timestamp(time_out) - unix_timestamp(time_in)) AS totalhours from hours where member_id='7'";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$rowNo = 1; //Increment Row Number
$total_time="00:00:00";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$time = $row['totalhours'];

$secs = strtotime($time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$total_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($total_time)+$secs);


echo "<tr align='left'>";    
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$rowNo++."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$row['member_name']."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_in']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_out']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$time." Hrs</font>.</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";          
}

?>          
</table>
<?php echo '<p align="right"><font size="4" color="black">Sub Total:</font> '.$total_time.' Hrs </p>'; ?>
```

What could be wrong here that after 12noon time is getting negative and all total login hours are displaying wrong?

Note: I'm not using `PDO` because this is an offline project not online.

Comment: `h` in a date mask is 12-hour clock; `H` is 24-hour clock

Comment: ah ley me give it a try

Comment: "and yes this is not pdo because its an offline project not online" Your assumption that PDO can't connect to localhost is misguided, I do it all the time.

Comment: it does i knw mate but this is a very old script converting it will take forever :)

Comment: i have attached an image please take a look the sub total hours don't seems ok

Comment: Try just `echo gmdate("H:i:s", $time);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because MySQL doesn't support passing a [meridiem](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/am-and-pm.html) (AM or PM), you need to properly pass things in 24 hour format. In order to store it properly, for example 1pm, instead of 1am, you would need to store `13:00:00`.

Use:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

(Capitol H) for 24 hour format.

See example 4 of the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation for PHP, where it mentions the MySQL format:

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y"); // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y"); // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd"); // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day'); // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.'); // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h'); // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s"); // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
?>
```

Comment: mate i have posted an image please take a look the sub total of all hours don't seems to be calculating well

Comment: @lalthung This will not fix old data that's already been inputted. You'll have to go and manually edit them in the database by adding 12 to the afternoon times. 1pm => 13, 2pm => 14, etc...My solution will fix things going forward

Comment: Also, how are you getting the sub total? Is this a different question? If so, you should [create a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: no not different its in the same question subtotal is displaying wrong 

$total_time="00:00:00";
$secs = strtotime($time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$total_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($total_time)+$secs);

Comment: thats what im wonder looks ok to me for it worked just fine earlier in the morning. starting to get a headache now

Comment: Try just `$total_time = gmdate("H:i:s", $time);`

Comment: I need to see what the values for `$time` are. `$time` should be the number of seconds between logout and login (Getting you the total login time in seconds). I followed [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3172358/4875631) to convert it to Hour:Minute:Second format.

Comment: if i echo echo $time = $row['totalhours'].; i get 00:13:27
00:00:06
00:00:58, 
00:00:04, 
00:00:04, 
00:01:04

Comment: Get rid of `sectotime` in mysql. Use the `gmdate` function in php to format it nicely, and just simply add up the seconds and use `gmdate` with php on the total (of seconds) to get the total in h:m:s format.