# PHP to convert integer to hh:mm:ss

Tags: php

I have a string in the format of hh:mm:ss that I convert to an integer representing the total number of seconds. For example:

```
01:43:03

01 * 3600
43 * 60
03 * 1
```

The above example results in an integer value of 6183.

After performing some logic using this value I then need to convert the integer back to a strict format of hh:mm:ss.

Note that this isn't a time of day. It is an amount of time. Like, I spent 1 hour, 43 minutes and 3 seconds driving from one point to another.

What is the shortest way of coding this conversion so that 6183 seconds is formatted as 01:43:03 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

Comment: Possible duplicate comments. +1 for both though. I honestly searched but didn't find this example. It's exactly what I needed.

Comment: The duplicate isn't a good choice. If you go over 24 hours it'll just cycle right back around to zero, at least not the accepted answer the 2nd answer is better.

Comment: @Augwa It's better, but the second answer doesn't format with leading zeros. Still, that post gave me what I needed.

Comment: make use of the `str_pad()` function to add your leading zero's.

Answer (score 2):

Use this-

```
echo $time = date("h:i:s A T",'6183');
```

I think it will help.

Comment: Waaa? Why are you including AM/PM and a Timezone identifier?

Comment: remove the A T and it won't up there.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use like this

```
<?php
    $total_seconds = 160183;
    $seconds = intval($total_seconds%60);
    $total_minutes = intval($total_seconds/60);
    $minutes = $total_minutes%60;
    $hours = intval($total_minutes/60);
    echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
?>
```

Check live demo : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78772e1462879ce3a20548a3a780df5de4e16e2c