# How to find time difference in Hours Minutes and seconds in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to calculate the time difference in Hours, Minutes and seconds between two-time intervals.

Here is my Code

```
 $actualLoginTime = strtotime('13:49:13.0000000');
 $loginTime = strtotime('09:00:00.0000000');
 $nInterval = ($actualLoginTime) - ($loginTime);
 {{date("H:i:s ", strtotime($nInterval))}}
```

It's giving me the wrong Output and showing the difference `5:00:00`.

Can you guys please help me.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42311841/2815635

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP to convert integer to hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311841/php-to-convert-integer-to-hhmmss)

Comment: Use `DateTime::diff()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my Question by using  `gmdate()` function:

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $nInterval );
```