# Twig template add leading zero with filter

Tags: php, twig

I'm converting an integer to a time format in the Twig template system. So that total duration of seconds is converted to `hh:mm:ss`.

Here is an example to how i convert hours:

```
{% filter round(0, 'floor') %}{{ agent.TotalCallDuration/3600 }}{% endfilter %}
```

Now I have to add leading zero to the hours if less than 10. I tried:

```
{% filter round(0, 'floor')|format('%02d') %}{{ agent.TotalCallDuration/3600 }}{% endfilter %}
```

But no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) filter with `timezone` argument set to `false`:

```
{{ agent.TotalCallDuration | date("H:i:s", false) }}
```

**For values bigger than 24 hours**

The above solution works only if the number of seconds is lesser than 86400 seconds (24 hours). For bigger values, I would write a simple filter using the `gmdate` function<sup>1</sup>, e.g.:

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('duration', function ($x) {
    return $x >= 86400 ? gmdate('d:H:i:s', $x - 86400) : gmdate('H:i:s', $x);
}));
```

where `$twig` is an instance of `Twig_Environment`.

Usage:

```
{{ agent.TotalCallDuration | duration }}
```

Another example where "days" are expressed in hours (`hh:mm:ss`):

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('duration', function ($x) {
    if ($x < 86400) {
        return gmdate('H:i:s', $x);
    }

    $hours = gmdate('G', $x);
    $days = (gmdate('d', $x) - 1) * 24 + $hours;
    return $days . gmdate(':i:s', $x);
}));
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Idea is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172358/1646322).</sub>

Comment: On closer review. It doesn't work. I have an example where agent.TotalCallDuration =  336651, that is converted to: 21:30:51, when it should have been well above than 95 hours.