# Get total hours and minutes from sum of time difference in php

Tags: php

I have a table to store machine start and stop records like that

```
 ---------------------------------------
|   machine_start   |   machine_stop    |
 ---------------------------------------
|       11:00 AM    |       11:00 PM    |
 ---------------------------------------
|       12:00 AM    |       01:00 PM    |
 ---------------------------------------
```

Now I want to get total machine operating time by first get the difference between machine_stop and machine_start time and loop through the table records to get the total time.

Here I have tried

```
$machine_total_time = 0;
foreach ($machine_data as $data){
    $machine_total_time += strtotime($data->machine_stop) - strtotime($data->machine_start);
}
var_dump(date("H:i", $machine_total_time));
```

It will show the highest 23 hours for **'H'**. I want to show the total hours and minutes from **$machine_total_time**. How to do that. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if the machine starts at `11 AM` and stops at `4 PM` two days later? Without dates, you won't know how long it was running.

Comment: :) Good Question. From your point of view, you are right. But this is just an example so that I can understand the basic problem.

Comment: @Joni he has to convert seconds to hours, what you've linked is not what op wants

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond This question has been asked and answered dozens if not hundreds of times on this site

Comment: Your code is fine all you need is to use one of the methods described in the duplicates to output your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gmdate()` function:

```
$minsec = gmdate("i:s", $machine_total_time); 
$hours = gmdate("d", $machine_total_time)*24 + gmdate("H", $machine_total_time);

$time = $hours . ':' . $minsec; // 56:12:12
```

Comment: Tried but not working. :)

Comment: What value do you have?

Comment: If i only print without gmdate or date then it shows 90000 or using the both function it shows 01:00:00

Comment: My bad, the hours reset after 24 but I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code, the total output should be 25 hours,

```
$machine_total_time = 0;
foreach ($machine_data as $data) {
    $time1    = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($data['machine_stop'])));
    $time2    = new DateTime(date("H:i:s", strtotime($data['machine_start'])));
    $interval = $time1->diff($time2);
    $machine_total_time += $interval->h;
}
echo $machine_total_time;
```

[interval documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) please refer to see options to fetch data from interval.