# How to convert seconds to DD:HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

I want to convert seconds to DD:HH:MM:SS format. I searched and found about dateJs but I couldnt understand it. Is there any simple method to convert seconds - 2490453 to DD:HH:MM:SS format? I am kinda newbie in Jquery so please help me!!