# Timer for only 30 mins

Tags: jquery, timer

I want to set a timer for example my product should be display for only 30 mins when it is added to cart. I tried :-

```
var d = new Date();

var minute = d.getHours()+30;
```

Also I want to show user how much time is remaining (countdown)

I know this is wrong. I want to do this using jQuery. I am new to jquery please help me on this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tag php accidentally or does it play a part here?

Comment: try https://github.com/robcowie/jquery-stopwatch

Comment: You can use setTimeOut method.

Comment: @Asad sorry for this I have removed php tag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> yeah this somewhat correct but I want to show user how much time is
>   remaining, i.e countdown should start.How to do that

Ok, how about this:

```
var countdown = 30 * 60 * 1000;
var timerId = setInterval(function(){
  countdown -= 1000;
  var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
  //var sec = Math.floor(countdown - (min * 60 * 1000));  // wrong
  var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);  //correct

  if (countdown <= 0) {
     alert("30 min!");
     clearInterval(timerId);
     //doSomething();
  } else {
     $("#countTime").html(min + " : " + sec);
  }

}, 1000); //1000ms. = 1sec.
```

Or I recommend you use these plugins:
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/09/jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Comment: excellent man genius.. Thanks its works but it show timer as :- 27 : 47000 I dont what this 000 at the end of secs how can I remove that ?

Comment: NP bro can you tell me how will I know 30 mins is passed away using this code ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @wf9a5m75 bro can you help on this -- I want this timer to be set on session im using php ?? How can I achive this ?

Comment: Oops, I thought you tagged "PHP", but not. Forget about it.

Comment: its give me client side timing ,If i want to use server side time then how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at javascript timers [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).  If you need to time for 30 minutes, try

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function()
{
    //doSomething
}, 1800000);
```

EDIT

To keep it from going off again later, use `window.clearInterval(timer);`

EDIT

If you want, you could keep track of how much time has passed, rather than have one big timer.

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
var secondsLeft;
var timer = window.setInterval(function()
{
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    secondsLeft = 1800 - ((now - startTime) / 1000);
    //do something here to display secondsLeft
}
```

Comment: yeah this somewhat correct but I want to show user how much time is remaining, i.e countdown should start.How to do that

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the link to MDN, which is a better resource than [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: You could possibly set an interval for every second to update a display of how much time is left.

Comment: @Asad, oh no prob.  But I probably overwrote it when I edited.  My bad

Comment: Can you show me an example how to achive this ,sorry but I am new to jquery

Comment: @RakeshShetty Added a brief example.  I am using actual time rather than just subtracting one second every time the function runs.  If you're doing something else, your function isn't guaranteed to be called on time.

Comment: yeah it is not subtracting from 30 mins for example if 30 min -- it should show like this 29 mins 59 sec ,29 mins 58 sec etc ... can you please tell me to how to achive this @Indigenuity ?

Comment: My answer right now reflects how to get how much time is left in seconds.  If you want to know how to convert seconds to Hours:Minutes:Seconds, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in Javascript, you can do it like this:

```
var waitTime = 30 * 60 * 1000; // = 30min.

setTimeout(function(){
  alert("30 min!");
}, waitTime);
```

And if you want to use jQuery, you can use jQuery Timer plugin.
http://jquery.offput.ca/every/

But I think if you use PHP and the system is shopping cart(or something), maybe you should do it using session mechanism of PHP.

Comment: yeah this somewhat correct but I want to show user how much time is remaining, i.e countdown should start.How to do that