# How to get two date-time diffrence

Tags: javascript

I m tryinng to get time diffrence using javascript.
I m implementing this things in iformbuilder.

Code

```
var date1 = $(".date1").val();
var date2 = $(".date2").val();
var d1=new Date(date1);
var d2=new Date(date2); 
var total=(((d2-d1)/1000*60)/60)
```

E.g

```
date1=2014/03/26 05:03
date2=2014/03/26 06:05
```

Expected output:

```
1:02
```

Current output:

```
3720
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript) (you already know how to get the difference, `d2 - d1` - you have a formatting issue.)

Comment: There are many assumptions here. What about the DST, timezone and what if the date changes? will the day, month and year of date will be same always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentOutput` is the difference in seconds. You can get the hours and minutes from it as:

```
var hrs = Math.floor(total/3600, 10);
var mins = (total%3600)/60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
document.write("Your Operation took  " + (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) + " milliseconds");
```