# How to convert seconds to HH:mm:ss in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I convert seconds to `HH:mm:ss`?

At the moment I am using the function below

```
render: function (data){
     return new Date(data*1000).toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");;
}
```

This works on chrome but in firefox for 12 seconds I get `01:00:12`
I would like to use moment.js for cross browser compatibility

I tried this but does not work

```
render: function (data){
         return moment(data).format('HH:mm:ss');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I managed to find a solution **without** moment.js which is as follow

```
return (new Date(data * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
```

Still curious on how I can do it in moment.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312993/javascript-seconds-to-time-string-with-format-hhmmss

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry for not having mentioned that I have already read that post. I need to render a table with millions of row and the solution there is too slow. the second answer is exactly what I have written in my question but gives me problems in firefox

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino so 4 trivial math operators is a problem for the task of mutating DOM for millions of elements? Are you sure you understand the performance problem correctly?

Comment: @zerkms well I know that my DAO classes have to be rewritten to serve the data already converted. This is an issue I am aware off. Said that I am quite happy with the current performances of my first attempt but when I have 5 math operations for a conversion that slows the system a bit. Yes I agree with you that this is just  a quick TEMPORARY solution

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino "that slows the system a bit" --- "a bit" is not how you reason about performance. **Is it** a bottleneck? Is it **proven** to be a bottleneck? If not - what drives you to optimize this very operation?

Comment: Moment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19457665/295783 - sounds slow

Comment: @mplungjan it will fail when it's summer/winter time boundaries

Comment: Ah - another reason not to use moment - one could set the start date to jan 1st though

Comment: @zerkms Looking at the console the load is of 412 ms against 365 ms. So 47 ms difference.

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino okay. So? You spent 34 minutes trying to optimize a problem that saves 47ms to render a million DOM nodes (which will take > 10 seconds). I think it's a great result*. * Actually it's not. PS: "412 ms against 365 ms" --- I'm sure now we need to guess what exactly these 2 numbers mean (since you didn't explain how the tests have been conducted)

Comment: @zerkms the reason why I spent 34 minutes is because it didn't work on Firefox. In order to rewrite the server side it will take me two weeks :( . I understand  this is not purist although. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Here is a solution without using moment js or regular expression : new Date(SECONDS * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);

Answer (score 97, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19457665/295783) I would try this to avoid leap issues

```
moment("2015-01-01").startOf('day')
    .seconds(s)
    .format('H:mm:ss');
```

I did not run jsPerf, but I would think this is faster than creating new date objects a million times

```
function pad(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function hhmmss(secs) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs = secs%60;
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
  minutes = minutes%60;
  return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(secs)}`;
  // return pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(secs); for old browsers
}
```

```js
function pad(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function hhmmss(secs) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs = secs%60;
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
  minutes = minutes%60;
  return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(secs)}`;
  // return pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(secs); for old browsers
}

for (var i=60;i<=60*60*5;i++) {
 document.write(hhmmss(i)+'<br/>');
}


/* 
function show(s) {
  var d = new Date();
  var d1 = new Date(d.getTime()+s*1000);
  var  hms = hhmmss(s);
  return (s+"s = "+ hms + " - "+ Math.floor((d1-d)/1000)+"\n"+d.toString().split("GMT")[0]+"\n"+d1.toString().split("GMT")[0]);
}    
*/
```

Comment: You could do this in the second example: return [hours, minutes, seconds].filter(t => t).map(pad).join(":")

Comment: @OnnoFaber What do you think is the fastest? concatenation or a filter plus a map? We could also do `\`${pad(hours)}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(secs)}\``

Comment: From all the answers before, the most simple is the one of [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan), but it has an error that shows random numbers if the value has milliseconds (for example: 17.3 s).
Based on his code, I propose the following: function pad(num) { return ("0" + num).slice(-2); } /** * @return {string} */ export default function renderUserTime (seconds){ let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60); const outputSecs = Math.round(seconds % 60); let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60); const outputMinutes = Math.round(minutes % 60); return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(outputMi

Answer (score 157):

This is similar to the answer mplungjan referenced from another post, but more concise:

```js
const secs = 456;

const formatted = moment.utc(secs*1000).format('HH:mm:ss');

document.write(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It suffers from the same caveats, e.g. if seconds exceed one day (86400), you'll not get what you expect.

Comment: thank you, i think this is a very common need, open a pull request to moment.js they should incorporate it.

Comment: Thanks @Sophie.  Few places mention utc(), which is exactly what was needed in my case.

Comment: Thats not work with seconds more as 24 hours like 90000 seconds.

Comment: @Sophie, it's not working for large second numbers.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [moment-duration-format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plugin:

```js
var seconds = 3820;
var duration = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds');
var formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss");
console.log(formatted); // 01:03:40
```

```html
<!-- Moment.js library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment-duration-format plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

See also this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okachynskyy/4ehb0L5p/)

Upd: To avoid trimming for values less than 60-sec use `{ trim: false }`:

```
var formatted = duration.format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false }); // "00:00:05"
```

Comment: There is a trade-off that needs to be looked at with your answer and @sophie's answer. While technically your solution will display a duration of "Time" as hh:mm:ss, it requires the extra plugin. Sophie's is a "Date" from the current point in time formatted to hh:mm:ss. If you removed the "utc" from Sophie's it could return incorrect information since it uses the epoch as the date and not the current point in time. Both answers work. Just something to think about and understand.

Comment: While here using the CDN and whatnot could add increased latency, it is generally dangerous to think of "including another library" as a negative tradeoff vs. implementing code yourself.  This is a trap I see many developers fall into and ultimately wind up with less maintainable code.

Comment: for some reason if seconds < 60 then it just ends up unformatted

Comment: @DanielLizik, just add { trim: false }. E.g.:
duration.format("hh:mm:ss", { trim: false });

Answer (score 19):

```
var seconds = 2000 ; // or "2000"
seconds = parseInt(seconds) //because moment js dont know to handle number in string format
var format =  Math.floor(moment.duration(seconds,'seconds').asHours()) + ':' + moment.duration(seconds,'seconds').minutes() + ':' + moment.duration(seconds,'seconds').seconds();
```

Answer (score 8):

My solution for changing **seconds (number) to string** format (for example: 'mm:ss'):

```
const formattedSeconds = moment().startOf('day').seconds(S).format('mm:ss');
```

Write **your** seconds instead **'S'** in example.
And just use the 'formattedSeconds' where you need.

Comment: This was the answer that I was looking for. Great advice but keep in mind that if you want to have hours displayed as well, make sure to use `HH:mm:ss` and not `hh:mm:ss` otherwise you will get `12:**:**` for durations less then 1 hour.

Answer (score 5):

In a better way to utiliza moments.js; you can convert the number of seconds to human-readable words like ( a few seconds, 2 minutes, an hour).

Example below should convert 30 seconds to "a few seconds"

```
moment.duration({"seconds": 30}).humanize()
```

Other useful features: "minutes", "hours"

Answer (score 5):

The above examples may work for someone but none did for me, so I figure out a much simpler approach

```
  var formatted = moment.utc(seconds*1000).format("mm:ss");
  console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: It worked for me! :)

Answer (score 4):

Until 24 hrs.
As `Duration.format` is deprecated, with moment@2.23.0

```
const seconds = 123;
moment.utc(moment.duration(seconds,'seconds').as('milliseconds')).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to correctly use moment.js durations?**
|
**Use moment.duration() in codes**

First, you need to import `moment` and `moment-duration-format`.

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-duration-format';
```

Then, use duration function. Let us apply the above example: 28800 = 8 am.

```js
moment.duration(28800, "seconds").format("h:mm a");
```

Well, you do not have above type error. Do you get a right value 8:00 am ? No…, the value you get is 8:00 a. Moment.js format is not working as it is supposed to.

The solution is to transform seconds to milliseconds and use UTC time.

```js
moment.utc(moment.duration(value, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm a')
```

All right we get 8:00 am now. If you want 8 am instead of 8:00 am for integral time, we need to do RegExp

```js
const time = moment.utc(moment.duration(value, 'seconds').asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm a');
time.replace(/:00/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

To display number of days along with hours, mins and seconds, you can do something like this:

```
const totalSec = 126102;
const remainingMillies= (totalSec % 86400) * 1000;
const formatted = `${Math.floor(totalSec / 86400)} day(s) and ${moment.utc(remainingMillies).format('hh:mm:ss')}`;
console.log(formatted );
```

will output :
1 day(s) and 11:01:42

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 no need for any new plugin just do this

Literally all you need in 2022 prints out duration in hh:mm:ss from two different date strings

```
<Moment format='hh:mm:ss' duration={startTime} date={endTime} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to use 3rd part libray/pluggin to get this task done

when using **momentJS version 2.29.4** :

```
  private getFormatedDuration(start: Date, end: Date): string {
    // parse 'normal' Date values to momentJS values
    const startDate = moment(start);
    const endDate = moment(end);

    // calculate and convert to momentJS duration 
    const duration = moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate));

    // retrieve wanted values from duration
    const hours = duration.asHours().toString().split('.')[0];
    const minutes = duration.minutes();

    // voilà ! without using any 3rd library ..
    return `${hours} h ${minutes} min`;
  }
```

supports also 24h format

PS : you can test and calculate by yourself using a 'decimal to time' calculator at [CalculatorSoup](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php)