# Momentjs - time difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Welcome ! I have single question. How to display difference from two inputs using moment.js? For now i have this code:

```
<script>

 var now  = document.getElementById('dep').value;
 var then = document.getElementById('arr').value;
 document.writeln(moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss")); // 1

</script>
```

and its not working dont' know why

Comment: do you want the difference in hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many other StackOverflow question/answers about this. 
To help you get started I placed a snippet. This will show the difference in days.
Check [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) for more information

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="date" id="dep" />
    <input type="date" id="arr" />
    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Test"/>
    <div id="test"></div>
   
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>

     <script>
         function test()
         {
             var now  = document.getElementById('dep').value;
             var then = document.getElementById('arr').value;
             document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = moment(now,"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"), "days");
         }
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and how to load it without clicking on button? just u enter values and it displays automatically

Comment: so on keyup keydown? sry but my javascript knowledge is very poor at this moment

Answer (score 0):

you can get the diff in seconds. I tried finding on the moment doc and couldnt find how to parse to a specific time format then it might need to be written.

```
function pad(num) {
    return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function hhmmss(secs) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  secs = secs%60;
  var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60)
  minutes = minutes%60;
  return pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(secs);
}

var diff = moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"), 'second')
document.writeln(hhmmss(diff))
```

ps. I took the snippet from [How to convert seconds to HH:mm:ss in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337370/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("Div-Tag-ID").value = ....` **instead of document.writeln**

You can just get the difference between two DateTime values

```
   moment('2013-11-16') - moment('2013-11-15')
```

Answer would be in miliseconds. As per this its 86400000 which is 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you wish to get the difference of times in seconds.

you can try the code below:

```
        var departure  = document.getElementById('dep').value;
        var arrival    = document.getElementById('arr').value;

        var startTime  = moment(departure, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        var endTime    = moment(arrival, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

        var duration   = endTime.diff(startTime, 'seconds');
```

you can change the format of time, i used 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'