# How to convert seconds to 10h 20m in moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, formatting, format, momentjs

How to convert seconds to 10h 20m in moment.js,
I did not find such a solution, who show 0h 01m(example)

```
result : 0h 01m
```

Comment: You don't need moment js. Hint, hours = seconds / 3600, minutes = the remaining seconds / 60 and seconds = the remaining seconds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert seconds to HH:mm:ss in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337370/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-in-moment-js)

Comment: moment.js can't do it?

Comment: You should know the answer already, you're supposed to have done some researches before posting a question

Comment: not, because this format has no text,
I want a result with string : 02h : 20m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use smth like this

```
seconds = 18100;
moment.utc(1000 * seconds).format('H[h] mm[m]'); // "5h 01m"
```

UPD: so if you need zeros then format could be

```
seconds = 3700;
moment.utc(1000 * seconds).format('HH[h] mm[m]'); // "01h 01m"
```