# Convert value into seconds using javascript moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

Is there a way to format `var timeValue = '65'` into `01:05` using moment.js? Its easier to format as ('HH:MM:SS') but passing a variable as 65 and converting into ('mm:ss') gives me response as '01:00' not '01:05',

**View**

```
<div id="app">
  <p>
  Time is {{roomTime}}
  </p>
  <br/>
  <p>
  How to make it display 01:05 not 01:00
  </p>
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return{
     roomTime: '',
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    var timeValue = '65'; /** As 65 is 1 minute and 5 seconds **/
    var formatTime = moment(timeValue).format("MM:SS");
    /** How to make 65 to be display as 01:05 **/
 
    this.roomTime = formatTime;
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

Below is my code reference in **JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/2x1ndpja/13/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert seconds to HH:mm:ss in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337370/how-to-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-in-moment-js)

Comment: Moment has a concept of [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) that could be leveraged to this end.  Unfortunately, the ability to [format a duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262621/how-do-i-use-format-on-a-moment-js-duration) has been missing for eight years or more.  There is a [github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463) requesting the formatting feature which has some alternative approaches and workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, you could use `moment` in this way:

```
var timeValue = '65';
moment().startOf('day')
    .seconds(timeValue)
    .format('mm:ss'))
```

Get the current date at the start of the day (`moment().startOf('day')`), add `timeValue` seconds (`.seconds(timeValue)`) and finally format (`.format('mm:ss')`).

The output will be `01:05`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eubdcjkf/2/) your code modified.

Comment: learned a new this as startOf('day') for moment.Js. Thank You its working now.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

`moment(String)` [uses the following parsing logic](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/):

> first check if the string matches known ISO 8601 formats, we then check if the string matches the RFC 2822 Date time format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found

`"65"` happens to be parsed as midnight UTC on Jan 1st 19**65**. If formatted as `mm:ss`, this gives `00:00`.

`moment(...)` can also take a number, in which case [it's treated as a unix timestamp in milliseconds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

You can therefore use the following:

```js
const seconds = 65

const ms = seconds * 1000

moment(ms).format('mm:ss')
```