# How to parse a string containing number of seconds to h/m/s format

Tags: javascript, time, datetime-format, string-parsing

I have a string that contains a number of seconds outputted by a timer (please note that the string is updated every second):

```
5162
```

How can I parse this string to hour/minute/second format in javascript?

Comment: `new Date( "5162" *1000).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0]` for <24 hours

Comment: search stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript

Comment: That was very helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to parse-just do some math.

Pseudocode:

```
sec=5162
hours = truncate(sec / 3600)
sec= sec modulo 3600
mins = truncate (sec/60)
sec = sec modulo 60
```

You don't mention what language you are using; in c, you can use sprintf to put all the pieces together into a string.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it with JavaScript, but I guess I wasn't clear enough