# How to format the elapsed time of setInterval method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer

I have a simple setInterval setup like so:

```
var time = 0;
function a(){
    window.setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

Which executes this function:

```
function timer() {
    time +=1;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = time + "s"
}
```

HTML is very simple for this. It just displays as `0s` and increases.

The problem I am having is that I can't seem to get it to display in a format like this `00:00:00`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This looks fine for incrementing the time. The trouble is in the code you're using to display the time in the HTML element. Could you share that code?

Comment: RobertAKARobin I edited it.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322798/2053389

Comment: @RobertAKARobin how would I actually use it though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot, using JS's built-in Date class, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279340/2053389):

```
function timer() {
  var date = new Date(null);
  date.setSeconds(time++);
  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}
```

Comment: Dude you are a genious thanks so much. Worked perfect! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create timer element

```
<div id="timer">
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Style

```
#timer > .hours:after,  #timer > .minutes:after{
    content: ":";
}
```

Update timer

```
var Timer = function(element){
    var secondsElement = element.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0],
        minutesElement = element.getElementsByClassName("minutes")[0],
        hoursElement   = element.getElementsByClassName("hours")[0],
        show = function(num){
            return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
        };

    return {
        update: function(){
            var now = new Date();
            secondsElement.innerHTML = show(now.getSeconds());
            minutesElement.innerHTML = show(now.getMinutes());
            hoursElement.innerHTML   = show(now.getHours());
        }
    };
};

var timer = new Timer(document.getElementById("timer"));

setInterval(function(){
    timer.update();
}, 500);
```