# Preventing overflow in JS Timer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, countdowntimer

I have done a timer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript) question's most voted answer.
Problem is, that when it reaches 0, it changes date to next day and starts a new 24 hour timer.

Tl;dr
00:00:00 -> 23:59:59 instead of staying 00:00:00 forever.

My current code:

```
function getTimeLeft() {
  var seconds_left = end_time - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  $('#test-time-left').text(time_left);
}
setInterval(getTimeLeft, 1000);
```

To keep 00:00:00, I thought of 2 ways of solving it.

First (and imho better) would be giving `setInterval(getTimeLeft, 1000);` in `while` loop with condition `seconds_left >= 0`. But I have few problems with that.

1. I have no idea how to pass variable outside of function.
2. I don't know if preventing setInterval will do anything, but I might as well just set interval to 0 (ergo turn it off).

Second approach would be simply doing `while` inside of function:

```
while( seconds_left >= 0){
      var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}
```

Problems:

1. Waste resources, because JS script is still being done

@Edit Final result:

```
function getTimeLeft() {
  var seconds_left = end_time - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  if (seconds_left <= 0)
  {
    seconds_left = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  $('#test-time-left').text(time_left);
}
var timer = setInterval(getTimeLeft, 1000);
```

I also set seconds_left to 0 just in case script miss 0 second frame (for example user closes browser while countdown happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to stop the timer when `seconds_left` equals 0, you could simply clear the interval:

```
function getTimeLeft() {
  var seconds_left = end_time - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  if(seconds_left === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);  // clear the interval
  }
  $('#test-time-left').text(time_left);
}

var timer = setInterval(getTimeLeft, 1000);  //save the timer in a variable
```

Note that your idea for using a while loop will *not* work:

```
while( seconds_left >= 0){
  var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}
```

JavaScript is single-threaded, which means the interval code will *not* run at all while your `while` loop is running, therefore creating an infinite loop (and possibly crashing your browser).

Comment: Is equal value and equal type necessary? I wanted to use <= instead of that. Just in case user close browser and javascript does not run and it miss 0 second frame. Please refer to edit in main post

Comment: If the user closes the browser, the interval will automatically be canceled.  Should be fine to use `<=` instead of `===`.

Comment: Interval does, but Date changes, but anyway everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with everything Rick Hithcock said.  Here is an example based on your code that sets the timer 10 seconds from now and then counts down.

```
var end_time = new Date();
end_time.setSeconds(end_time.getSeconds() + 10);

function getTimeLeft() {
    var now = new Date();
    var seconds_left = (end_time - now) / 1000;
    if (seconds_left <= 1) {
        clearInterval(timerID);
    }
    var time_left = new Date(seconds_left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    $('#test-time-left').text(time_left);
}
timerID = setInterval(getTimeLeft, 1000);
```