# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert seconds to `hh:mm:ss` format with javascript. I found a lot of topics about this like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript), but I still have trouble implementing this.

This is my code:

```
function buildList(item, index) {
....
    var listItemTime = $('.time', listItem);
      listItemTime.html(secondsToHms(item.time));
      $('#dataList').append(listItem);
}

function secondsToHms(d) {
      var time = (new Date).clearTime()
              .addSeconds(d)
              .toString('H:mm:ss');

    console.log(time);
    return time;
}
```

I got an error: `TypeError: (new Date(...)).clearTime is not a function`

I also tried to use moment:

```
function secondsToHms(d) {
      return moment().startOf('day')
            .seconds(d)
            .format('H:mm:ss');
}
```

And I got the error:

> moment is not defined

I installed moment with `npm install moment --save` and then tried to require it, but the component was not working anymore.

Comment: this question is  duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

Comment: @j.doe are you trying do it on angular platform

Comment: Are you using node js application?

Answer (score 2):

`clearTime` is a function of `Datejs`, which is an additional dependency you would need to pull in. Unless you link DateJs to your code, e.g. by including

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>`

in your `<head>` block, you will see anerror that the method does not exist.

You may want to instead use the standard library function [`toTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString). Which outputs results like this `14:26:27 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`.

As an alternative, if `HH:mm:ss` format is essential, you can use the following code to print the required string.

```
function secondsToHms(d) {    
    var hours = d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')    
    var minutes = d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')    
    var seconds = d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')

    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
}
```

Both of these methods can be seen running in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqo0mjgo/16/)

Comment: Note that this will include results like `9:40:2` or `10:8:14`, which probably wouldn't be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Scott, you are completely correct, I've updated the fiddle in my answer to fix this issue using `padStart` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998822/6809918) answer

Comment: Please update the answer as well.  Fiddles are fine, but important code should also be included in the answer.

Comment: d is the number of second I want to convert. I tried your code as following:

 function secondsToHms(s) {
  var d = new Date(0);
  d.setSeconds(s);
var time = d.getHours()...

but I get an extra hour. the result looks like  01:33:20 where it should be 00:33:20

Comment: j, I think you probably need to use `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes` and `getUTCSeconds`. It sounds like your local timezone is UTC + 1

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a lot more that needs to be done with dates, this is too simple a problem to bring in [DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/), [Moment](https://momentjs.com/), or -- my preference -- [date-fp](https://github.com/cullophid/date-fp).

You can simply write it like this:

```
const secondsToHms = s => ({
  hours: (s - s % 3600) / 3600, 
  minutes: ((s - s % 60) / 60) % 60, 
  seconds: s % 60
})
```

And then format the result of that however you like.

(**Note**, four years later: a downvote made me look at this old answer, and realize that it was wrong for larger number of hours.  This should be fixed now.)