# Creating a session timeout function, which can display timer and redirect to previous page on timeout in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, session, routerlink

I want to create a session timeout function for a payment page, where the timer will be displayed in my webpage and after 5 minutes, the payment session will expire and user is redirected to the previous page. I am using angular 4 for my front end, so using `href` is not entertained, i want a solution involving just `javascript` and `routerLink` and `typescript`. Any suggestions?

I am using this function to show the timer on webpage, its working but not am unable to use routerLink here to redirect to previous page.

```
paymentSessionTimer() {
let downloadButton = document.getElementById("paymentSession");
var counter = 600;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "10";
var id;
this.redirectFlag = "false";

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if(counter < 0) {
      newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
      clearInterval(id);

      this.redirectFlag = "true";     
      //this.router.navigate(['../search']);
  } else {
    newElement.innerHTML = counter.toString() + " seconds left.";  
  }
}, 1000);
this.router.navigate(['../previous']);
```

}

Comment: What did you try so far ? For security reasons, a backend solution will always be required for this kind of purpose.

Comment: That doesn't mean he can't make a pretty page with a timer on the front end

Comment: I am not going for backend, i just want to show an alert message and want to redirect to previous page.

Comment: @ibenjelloun i have added the function i am using , can it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

timer = {s: 0, mn: 0};

constructor(private location: Location) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.location.back();
  }, 300000);

  setInterval(() => {
    this.timer.s += 1;
    if (this.timer.s > 59) {
      this.timer.s = 0;
      this.timer.mn += 1;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Now you can display a timer and the user will be redirected.

If you want a reverted timer :

```
    this.timer.s -= 1;
    if (this.timer.s < 0) {
      this.timer.s = 59;
      this.timer.mn = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Do i need to install Location module? @trichetriche

Comment: No, it's part of the `common` module, which is one of the core modules.

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined` getting this error for `this.timer.s`

Comment: Did you declare `timer` as a member of your class ? (and I know where you get that error from, don't worry)

Comment: Ohh crap, sorry i was missing the declaration of timer

Comment: Well, i didn't used this solution, but modified my own function for redirection also. But thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't see your function, but you should avoid doign that. DOM modification should be made only by Angular, not by you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that like this.

in your component ts file.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.routerNavigate(['/routeYouWantToNavigate']);
     }, 300000);
  }
```

Comment: There's a method made for returning to the previous page, and there's no timer in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using rxjs [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) Observable and some operators would be a clean solution.

You could create two observables (the `secondsToStringDate` function should be implemented, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279340/8945135)) :

```
// Fires every second for 5 minutes then completes
sessionExpiration$ = timer(1000).pipe(take(60 * 5));

// Every second, generate a displayable string mm:ss
sessionRemainingTime$ = sessionExpiration$
 .pipe(map(seconds => secondsToStringDate(seconds)));
```

Now that you created your Observables, you can use them :

To run the desired behavior when the time expires :

```
sessionExpiration$.pipe(finalize(() => {
    // Fired when the sessionExpiration$ observable completes
    // You can put what you want to do when session expires
}).subscribe();
```

To add where you want to display time in your template :

```
<!-- Will display the time in the template --> 
{{sessionRemainingTime$ | async}}
```

For a secure solution, you should add a backend solution and not rely only on the javascript.