# Countdown action when finished

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I need add action when finish coutdown in this code
so when the countdown is finished I can run certain commands, like the show button.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
            if(event.data==1) { // playing
                myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
                    var time;
                    time = player.getCurrentTime();
                    $("#timeHolder").text(time);
                }, 100);
            }
            else { // not playing
                clearInterval(myTimer);
            }
        }
```

thank you

Comment: What format does `player.getCurrentTime()` return?

Comment: player.getCurrentTime() is second format

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript

Comment: thank you very much, I have found it and the problem is solved.