# Automatically Convert User Inputted Seconds To HH:MM:SS Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this very simple `Vanilla JS + HTML` code wherein I can input my desired number of seconds and it will countdown on `button` click. I need help improving this code wherein, instead of counting down the inputted seconds, it will convert the seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds on `button` click and it will countdown the result at the same time. Think of it as a seconds to HH:MM:SS converter + Countdown.

**Note:** I want to run this code offline without dependencies. So, I will greatly appreciate it if we can come up with a solution using Vanilla JS. As simple as this may be for most, my knowhow in JS programming is really mediocre. Sorry. Thanks for the help and suggestions in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <p>Input Seconds:</p>
    <input id="number" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="button" id="start">Start Timer</button>
</form>
<div id="area"><p id="text1" style="color: red;">Click Start</p></div>
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

```
<script>
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    start.onclick = finalCountDown;
}

function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown(),1000);}

function countDown(){
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var value = parseInt(number.value, 10);
    var area = document.getElementById("text1");
    var audio = new Audio('audioURL.mp3');
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (value > 1) {
            area.innerText = value-1;
            value--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            area.innerText = "Countdown Ended";
            audio.play()
        }
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate (down to the answer) of [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it by using the below line.

```
 var timer = new Date(value * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
```

and use the `timer` value in the innerHtml

```js
window.onload = init;
function init(){
    var start = document.getElementById("start");
    start.onclick = finalCountDown;
}

function finalCountDown() {setTimeout(countDown(),1000);}

function countDown(){
    var number = document.getElementById("number");
    var value = parseInt(number.value, 10);
            
    var area = document.getElementById("text1");
            
    var audio = new Audio('audioURL.mp3');
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
    
    var timer  = new Date(value * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)

        if (value > 1) {
            area.innerText = timer 
            value--;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            area.innerText = "Countdown Ended";
            audio.play()
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <p>Input Seconds:</p>
    <input id="number" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
    <button type="button" id="start">Start Timer</button>
</form>
<div id="area"><p id="text1" style="color: red;">Click Start</p></div>
```