# second to days month years in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have numbers that represent seconds. I want to know how I should get years, months, and days of it in Javascript.
for example, X second means five years and six months, and 22 days
how I should write a code that gets these from the second I gave.

Comment: this old thread will surely help you out : [good luck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279340/17024672)

Comment: @nEo please use the link Hen Moshe provided, this is a very common question and that link will point you in the best direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert seconds to HH-MM-SS with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322732/convert-seconds-to-hh-mm-ss-with-javascript)

Comment: The answer will be an approximate number of years, months, and days because the number of seconds in a year depends if the year is a leap year or not; also the number of seconds in the month of Feb will be different than that in March.